# Most appropriate MPI_Datatype for "block decomposition"?

Tags: c, mpi, parallel-processing

With the help from [Jonathan Dursi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463827/jonathan-dursi) and [osgx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196561/osgx), I've now done the "row decomposition" among the processes:

[row http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/9118/ghostcells.jpg](http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/9118/ghostcells.jpg)

---

Now, I'd like to try the "block decomposition" approach (pictured below):
[block http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/9682/ghostcellsblock.jpg](http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/9682/ghostcellsblock.jpg)

How should one go about it? This time, the `MPI_Datatype` will be necessary, right? **Which datatype would be most appropriate/easy to use?** Or can it plausibly be done without a datatype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always make do without a datatype by just creating a buffer and copying the buffer as count of the underlying type; that's conceptually the simplest.  On the other hand, it slower and it actually involves a lot more lines of code.  Still, it can be handy when you're trying to get something to work, and then you can implement the datatype-y version along side that and make sure you're getting the same answers.

For the ghost-cell filling, in the i direction you don't need a type, as it's similar to what you had been doing; but you can use one, [`MPI_Type_contiguous`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Type_contiguous.html), which just specifies a count of some type (which you can do anyway in your send/recv).

For ghost-cell filling in the j direction, probably easiest is to use [`MPI_Type_Vector`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Type_vector.html).  If you're sending the rightmost column of (say) an array with i=0..N-1, j=0..M-1 you want to send a vector with count=N, blocksize=1, stride=M.  That is, you're sending count chunks of 1 value, each separated by M values in the array.

You can also use [`MPI_Type_create_subarray`](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Type_create_subarray.html) to pull out just the region of the array you want; that's probably a little overkill in this case.

Now, if as in your previous question you want to be able at some point to gather all the sub-arrays onto one processor, you'll probably be using subarrays, and part of the question is answered here: [MPI_Type_create_subarray and MPI_Gather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585630/mpi-type-create-subarray-and-mpi-gather) .  Note that if your array chunks are of different sizes, though, then things start getting a little tricker.

(Actually, why are you doing the gather onto one processor, anyway?  That'll eventually be a scalability bottleneck.  If you're doing it for I/O, once you're comfortable with data types, you can use MPI-IO for this..)

Comment: Jonathan, thank for the exhaustive answer; I must apologize for not responding sooner.

The gathering-onto-root is just one (of 2) ways that I know of to do the output (the other being `[f]printf` which, as I've read, is notoriously hard to implement correctly).

Comment: Work on this for a while until you're comfortable with it, then after a bit ask a question about using MPI-IO to read/write the data to file.   Trust me, it's easier than it sounds.