# MPI ghost-cell exchange with MPI_Type_create_subarray or MPI_Type_vector/contigous

Tags: subdomain, mpi

I am currently trying to implement a simulation similar to a diffusion in 2D. I want to speed up the process by using domain composition, splitting the total domain automatically in the right chunks (according to the hardware - MPI_Dims_create). I then exchange after each iteration the ghost cells (since they are required for the next iteration) between the neighbouring cells/processes.
I implemented the whole with cartesian coordinates (MPI_Cart_create), so i split the whole domain in chunks of Nx*Ny cells with different dimensions Nx and Ny. I already have the conceptually simplest implementation with buffers, but i want to use now MPI Types to improve performance.

The question i currently face is if there is a way to build the ghost cells using subarrays or do i have to use the vector MPI Type? I found the hint to the subarray [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598578/most-appropriate-mpi-datatype-for-block-decomposition/6600095#6600095), but i think i can't use it to build subarrays from discontinous memory. Is this assumption correct and should i best use MPI_Type_vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question i currently face is if there is a way to build the ghost cells using subarrays or do i have to use the vector MPI Type?

You could use MPI_Type_create_subarray to implement ghost cell exchange but I think it's overkill. It's main purpose is for facilitating access to a global array spread over many processors. With MPI you ideally want to use a local solution, which in this case is to pack the data and pass only between adjacent processes. This avoids collective operations which scale badly for large numbers of processors.

Manually packing buffers as you have is probably fairly efficient. MPI_types simplify this packing process, but doesn't necessarily speed it up (An example of using MPI_TYPES for ghost cell exchange is given in "Using MPI: Portable Parallel Programming with the Message-passing" By William Gropp, Ewing Lusk, Anthony Skjellum).

Whatever you do, MPI will have to make strided data access and copy data to prepare the buffers used in the exchange of ghost cell data.

Comment: Indeed chapter 4.7 (second edition) contains the usage of vector. Still I didn't find anything about the MPI_Type_create_subarray routine in the book (i only possess the 2nd edition). Is there more to be found in newer editions?

Comment: I was reading some more in books and suppose the best way to do what i want is indeed to follow the advice in the link i gave in first place. Then once the calculations are done, MPI subarrays can be used to gather the whole chunks of the "submatrices". I guess it's also possible to use the subarrays to build the ghost-cells, but i suppose that MPI vector and contiguous are more handy for this approach.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a copy of MPI book anymore so was going from memory (1st edition). I think sub array may be overkill for what you want -- it's more for facilitating access to a global array over many processors than the adjacent processor exchange you need for a diffusive solver. I've always manually packed buffers assuming MPI_types simplify this packing process, not speed it up (I think they even say in either Using MPI or MPI-2.0 types are slower but should get better). Whatever you do, your code or MPI will have to make strided data access and copy data to prepare he ghost cell data...

Comment: Also, MPI_Type_create_subarray was introduced in the MPI-2 standard so won't be in the first book (in Using MPI-2: Advanced Features of the Message-Passing Interface by the same authors). Although, like you said in your last comment, I think using MPI_types and an MPI_gatherv at the end would be the way to go.

Comment: This is not an answer (or at least does not provide a comprehensive solution) and should have been posted as a comment instead.

Comment: Agreed but not enough rep to post and thought an answer was better than none