# MPI Point to Point Communication to Collective Communication: MPI_Scatterv Trouble

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am working on a project of converting a Point to Point Communication to a Collective Communication.

Essentially, what I would like to do is use MPI_Scatterv instead of MPI_Send and MPI_Recv.  What I am having trouble determining is the correct arguments for Scatterv.

Here is the function that I am working in:

```
    void read_block_vector (
    char        *s,      /* IN - File name */
    void       **v,      /* OUT - Subvector */
    MPI_Datatype dtype,  /* IN - Element type */
    int         *n,      /* OUT - Vector length */
    MPI_Comm     comm)   /* IN - Communicator */
{
   int        datum_size;   /* Bytes per element */
   int        i;
   FILE      *infileptr;    /* Input file pointer */
   int        local_els;    /* Elements on this proc */
   MPI_Status status;       /* Result of receive */
   int        id;           /* Process rank */
   int        p;            /* Number of processes */
   int        x;            /* Result of read */

   datum_size = get_size (dtype);
   MPI_Comm_size(comm, &p);
   MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &id);

   /* Process p-1 opens file, determines number of vector
      elements, and broadcasts this value to the other
      processes. */

   if (id == (p-1)) {
      infileptr = fopen (s, "r");
      if (infileptr == NULL) *n = 0;
      else fread (n, sizeof(int), 1, infileptr);
   }
   MPI_Bcast (n, 1, MPI_INT, p-1, comm);
   if (! *n) {
      if (!id) {
         printf ("Input file '%s' cannot be opened\n", s);
         fflush (stdout);
      }
   }

   /* Block mapping of vector elements to processes */

   local_els = BLOCK_SIZE(id,p,*n);

   /* Dynamically allocate vector. */

   *v = my_malloc (id, local_els * datum_size);
   if (id == (p-1)) {
      for (i = 0; i < p-1; i++) {
         x = fread (*v, datum_size, BLOCK_SIZE(i,p,*n),
            infileptr);
         MPI_Send (*v, BLOCK_SIZE(i,p,*n), dtype, i, DATA_MSG,
            comm);
      }
      x = fread (*v, datum_size, BLOCK_SIZE(id,p,*n),
             infileptr);
      fclose (infileptr);
   } else {
      MPI_Recv (*v, BLOCK_SIZE(id,p,*n), dtype, p-1, DATA_MSG,
         comm, &status);
   }
 // My Attempt at making this collective communication:
if(id == (p-1))
    {
        x = fread(*v,datum_size,*n,infileptr);

        for(i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            size[i] = BLOCK_SIZE(i,p,*n);

        }
        //x = fread(*v,datum_size,BLOCK_SIZE(id, p, *n),infileptr);
        fclose(infileptr);
    }
     MPI_Scatterv(v,send_count,send_disp, dtype, storage, size[id], dtype, p-1, comm);

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I'm assuming you've taken a look at http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Scatterv.html (the first result from a Google search)? What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: I did take a look at that.  It was very helpful.  It turns out that my errors were actually coming from dynamic memory allocation problems.  I was able work through and figure those out.

Thanks for your willingness to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier for people to answer your question if you post a small, self-contained, reproducible example.

For the [Scatterv](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Scatterv.html), you need to provide the list of counts to send to each process, which appears to be your `size[]` array, and the displacements within the data to send out.  The mechanics of Scatter vs Scatterv are described in some detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269399/sending-blocks-of-2d-array-in-c-using-mpi/9271753#9271753).  Trying to infer what all your variables and un-supplied functions/macros do, the example below scatters a file out to the processes.

But also note that if you're doing this, it's not much harder to actually use [MPI-IO](http://beige.ucs.indiana.edu/B673/node179.html) to coordinate the file access directly, avoiding the need to have one process read all of the data in the first place.   Code for that is also supplied.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int id, p;
    int *block_size;
    int datasize = 0;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);

    block_size = malloc(p * sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0; i<p; i++) {
        block_size[i] = i + 1;
        datasize += block_size[i];
    }

    /* create file for reading */
    if (id == p-1) {
        char *data = malloc(datasize * sizeof(char));
        for (int i=0; i<datasize; i++)
            data[i] = 'a' + i;

        FILE *f = fopen("data.dat","wb");
        fwrite(data, sizeof(char), datasize, f);
        fclose(f);

        printf("Initial data: ");
        for (int i=0; i<datasize; i++)
            printf("%c", data[i]);
        printf("\n");
        free(data);
    }

    if (id == 0) printf("---Using MPI-Scatterv---\n");

    /* using scatterv */

    int local_els = block_size[id];
    char *v = malloc ((local_els + 1) * sizeof(char));
    char *all;

    int *counts, *disps;
    counts = malloc(p * sizeof(int));
    disps  = malloc(p * sizeof(int));

    /* counts.. */
    for(int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        counts[i] = block_size[i];

    /* and displacements (where the data starts within the send buffer) */
    disps[0] = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < p; i++)
        disps[i] = disps[i-1] + counts[i-1];

    if(id == (p-1))
    {
        all = malloc(datasize*sizeof(char));

        FILE *f = fopen("data.dat","rb");
        int x = fread(all,sizeof(char),datasize,f);
        fclose(f);
    }

    MPI_Scatterv(all, counts, disps, MPI_CHAR, v, local_els, MPI_CHAR, p-1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (id == (p-1)) {
        free(all);
    }

    v[local_els] = '\0';
    printf("[%d]: %s\n", id, v);

    /* using MPI I/O */

    fflush(stdout);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);   /* only for syncing output to screen */

    if (id == 0) printf("---Using MPI-IO---\n");

    for (int i=0; i<local_els; i++)
        v[i] = 'X';

    /* create the file layout - the subarrays within the 1d array of data */
    MPI_Datatype myview;
    MPI_Type_create_subarray(1, &datasize, &local_els, &(disps[id]),
                                MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_CHAR, &myview);
    MPI_Type_commit(&myview);

    MPI_File mpif;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "data.dat", MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &mpif);

    MPI_File_set_view(mpif, (MPI_Offset)0, MPI_CHAR, myview, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
    MPI_File_read_all(mpif, v, local_els, MPI_CHAR, &status);

    MPI_File_close(&mpif);
    MPI_Type_free(&myview);

    v[local_els] = '\0';
    printf("[%d]: %s\n", id, v);

    free(v);
    free(counts);
    free(disps);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Running this gives (output re-ordered for clarity)

```
$ mpirun -np 6 ./foo
Initial data: abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
---Using MPI-Scatterv---
[0]: a
[1]: bc
[2]: def
[3]: ghij
[4]: klmno
[5]: pqrstu
---Using MPI-IO---
[0]: a
[1]: bc
[2]: def
[3]: ghij
[4]: klmno
[5]: pqrstu
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience and for drawing my attention to MPI-IO.  I will make sure to look into this.

Your code has been very helpful in understanding how to work with Scatterv.

It turns out that another major problem of mine was dealing with dynamic memory allocation.  I was misinterpreting these errors as errors in my Scatterv arguments.