# Scatter array to only worker tasks

Tags: c++, mpi, scatter

I have an array that stores arrays (called sendbuff), and I would like to send those arrays to other threads by using MPI::Scatter.

```
                        sendbuff
   #####    ###############################
p  # 0 # -> # -1 # -1 # -1 # -1 # -1 # -1 # (values)
o  #####    ###############################
s  # 1 # -> # -1 # -1 # -1 # -1 # -1 # -1 # (values)
   #####    ###############################
```

As it can be seen, `sendbuff[0]` holds an array of size 6 that has 6 values (all -1) and `sendbuff[1]` has the same thing. I want to send those arrays of -1 to the other threads, and save them in an array called recvbuff that is filled with 0s:

```
        recvbuff
#########################
# 0 # 0 # 0 # 0 # 0 # 0 #
#########################
```

I researched OS for answers and I found some, but they use MPI_Datatype but I would like to avoid it.
To try and achieve this goal I made the following code that doesn't work:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[]){

    //variable innitialization
    int taskid, ntasks, buffsize, **sendbuff, *recvbuff;

    MPI::Init(argc, argv);

    taskid = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
    ntasks = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();    

    buffsize = 6;

    //memory innitialization
    recvbuff = new int[buffsize];
    sendbuff = new int*[ntasks];
    for(int i = 0; i < ntasks; i++){
        sendbuff[i] = new int[buffsize];
    }

    //array innitialization
    for(int i = 0; i < buffsize; i++){
        recvbuff[i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < ntasks; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < buffsize; j++){
            sendbuff[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }

    //communication
    MPI::COMM_WORLD.Scatter(sendbuff[0], buffsize, MPI::INT, recvbuff, buffsize,
        MPI::INT, 0);

    //output
    for(int i = 0; i < buffsize; i++){
        cout<<"Task"<<taskid<<" recvbuff["<<i<<"] = "<<recvbuff[i] << endl;
    }

    //cleaning
    for(int i = 0; i < ntasks; i++){
            delete[] sendbuff[i];
    }
    delete[] sendbuff;
    delete[] recvbuff;


    MPI::Finalize();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

After using scatter, I would expect he `recvbuff` variable to be filled with -1 values, however I get a mix of -1 and garbage like this:

```
$ mpirun -np 3 a.out 
Task0 recvbuff[0] = -1
Task0 recvbuff[1] = -1
Task0 recvbuff[2] = -1
Task0 recvbuff[3] = -1
Task0 recvbuff[4] = -1
Task0 recvbuff[5] = -1    
Task1 recvbuff[0] = 33
Task1 recvbuff[1] = 0
Task1 recvbuff[2] = -1
Task1 recvbuff[3] = -1
Task1 recvbuff[4] = -1
Task1 recvbuff[5] = -1
Task2 recvbuff[0] = -1
Task2 recvbuff[1] = -1
Task2 recvbuff[2] = 33
Task2 recvbuff[3] = 0
Task2 recvbuff[4] = 1768975727
Task2 recvbuff[5] = 7496543
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance, Pedro.

Comment: I think you want to use MPI_Broadcast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scatter and gather are described in some detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269399/sending-blocks-of-2d-array-in-c-using-mpi/9271753#9271753).   Scatter splits up data and scatters the pieces to other tasks, but the data has to be stored in contiguous memory - MPI_Scatter has no way of knowing it needs to follow pointers and if so, how many -  and the way you're allocating sendbuff:

```
sendbuff = new int*[ntasks];
for(int i = 0; i < ntasks; i++){
    sendbuff[i] = new int[buffsize];
}
```

the different rows of sendbuff could be scattered all over system memory.  You'll be almost there if you allocate the data contiguously:

```
sendbuff = new int*[ntasks];
sendbuff[0] = new int[ntasks * 6];
for(int i = 1; i < ntasks; i++){
    sendbuff[i] = &(sendbuff[0][i*6];
}
```

Now you should be able to scatter, but be aware that row 0 will go to rank 0; that is, scatter goes to *all* the processes in the communicator.   If you are only trying to send to your non-rank-zero tasks, the simplest thing to do is to just keep a row of dummy data in sendbuff for rank 0 so that a normal scatter works correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rank, size;
    const int nelem = 6;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int **sendbuff = new int*[size];
    int *recvbuff  = new int[nelem];

    if (rank == 0) {
        sendbuff[0] = new int[nelem * size];
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            sendbuff[i] = &(sendbuff[0][nelem*i]);

        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<nelem; j++)
                sendbuff[i][j] = i-1;
    }

    MPI_Scatter(sendbuff[0], nelem, MPI_INT, recvbuff, nelem, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank != 0) {
        std::cout << "Scatter: [ " << rank << "]: ";
        for (int i=0; i<nelem; i++)
            std::cout << recvbuff[i] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;

        for (int i=0; i<nelem; i++)
            recvbuff[i] *= recvbuff[i];
    }

    MPI_Gather(recvbuff, nelem, MPI_INT, sendbuff[0], nelem, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == 0) {
        for (int j=1; j<size; j++) {
            std::cout << "Gather: [ " << j << "]: ";
            for (int i=0; i<nelem; i++)
                    std::cout << sendbuff[j][i] << " ";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    delete [] recvbuff;
    if (rank == 0)
        delete [] sendbuff[0];
    delete [] sendbuff;

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Note that we're scattering the data, the workers are squaring the numbers, and the master gathers it back.  Compiling and running gives:

```
$ mpic++ -o intercomm intercomm.cxx
$ mpirun -np 4 ./intercomm
Scatter: [ 2]: 1 1 1 1 1 1
Scatter: [ 1]: 0 0 0 0 0 0
Scatter: [ 3]: 2 2 2 2 2 2
Gather: [ 1]: 0 0 0 0 0 0
Gather: [ 2]: 1 1 1 1 1 1
Gather: [ 3]: 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

If you'd rather avoid having dummy data for rank 0 -- perhaps is large -- you can break up the tasks into two groups, the master task and the worker tasks, and set up an [intercommunicator](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node111.html) that allows collective communications between them.   Here's a simple program which does just that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Comm   localComm;    /* intra-communicator of local sub-group */
    MPI_Comm   interComm;    /* inter-communicator */
    int masterworker;
    int rank, size;
    const int nelem = 6;
    int rootrank;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    masterworker = (rank == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, masterworker, rank, &localComm);

    if (masterworker == 0)
    {
        MPI_Intercomm_create( localComm, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1, 1, &interComm);
        rootrank = ( rank == 0 ? MPI_ROOT : MPI_PROC_NULL );
    }
    else {
        MPI_Intercomm_create( localComm, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0, 1, &interComm);
        rootrank = 0;
    }

    int **sendbuff = new int*[size-1];
    int *recvbuff  = new int[nelem];

    if (rank == 0) {

        sendbuff[0] = new int[nelem * (size-1)];
        for (int i=1; i<size-1; i++)
            sendbuff[i] = &(sendbuff[0][nelem*i]);

        for (int i=0; i<size-1; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<nelem; j++)
                sendbuff[i][j] = i;
    }

    MPI_Scatter(sendbuff[0], nelem, MPI_INT, recvbuff, nelem, MPI_INT, rootrank, interComm);

    if (masterworker == 1) {
        std::cout << "Scatter: [ " << rank << "]: ";
        for (int i=0; i<nelem; i++)
            std::cout << recvbuff[i] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;

        for (int i=0; i<nelem; i++)
            recvbuff[i] *= recvbuff[i];
    }

    MPI_Gather(recvbuff, nelem, MPI_INT, sendbuff[0], nelem, MPI_INT, rootrank, interComm);
    if (masterworker == 0) {
        for (int j=0; j<size-1; j++) {
            std::cout << "Gather: [ " << j << "]: ";
            for (int i=0; i<nelem; i++)
                    std::cout << sendbuff[j][i] << " ";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }




    MPI_Comm_free(&interComm);
    MPI_Comm_free(&localComm);
    delete [] recvbuff;
    if (rank == 0)
        delete [] sendbuff[0];
    delete [] sendbuff;

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Again, compiling and running gives:

```
$ mpic++ -o intercomm intercomm.cxx
$ mpirun -np 4 ./intercomm
Scatter: [ 1]: 0 0 0 0 0 0
Scatter: [ 2]: 1 1 1 1 1 1
Scatter: [ 3]: 2 2 2 2 2 2
Gather: [ 0]: 0 0 0 0 0 0
Gather: [ 1]: 1 1 1 1 1 1
Gather: [ 2]: 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Alternately, if you don't want to mess around with intercommunicators, just keep a row of dummy data in sendbuff for rank 0 so that a normal scatter works correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rank, size;
    const int nelem = 6;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int **sendbuff = new int*[size];
    int *recvbuff  = new int[nelem];

    if (rank == 0) {
        sendbuff[0] = new int[nelem * size];
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            sendbuff[i] = &(sendbuff[0][nelem*i]);

        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<nelem; j++)
                sendbuff[i][j] = i-1;
    }

    MPI_Scatter(sendbuff[0], nelem, MPI_INT, recvbuff, nelem, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank != 0) {
        std::cout << "Scatter: [ " << rank << "]: ";
        for (int i=0; i<nelem; i++)
            std::cout << recvbuff[i] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;

        for (int i=0; i<nelem; i++)
            recvbuff[i] *= recvbuff[i];
    }

    MPI_Gather(recvbuff, nelem, MPI_INT, sendbuff[0], nelem, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == 0) {
        for (int j=1; j<size; j++) {
            std::cout << "Gather: [ " << j << "]: ";
            for (int i=0; i<nelem; i++)
                    std::cout << sendbuff[j][i] << " ";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    delete [] recvbuff;
    if (rank == 0)
        delete [] sendbuff[0];
    delete [] sendbuff;

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

And again compiling and running gives:

```
$ mpic++ -o intercomm intercomm.cxx
$ mpirun -np 4 ./intercomm
Scatter: [ 2]: 1 1 1 1 1 1
Scatter: [ 1]: 0 0 0 0 0 0
Scatter: [ 3]: 2 2 2 2 2 2
Gather: [ 1]: 0 0 0 0 0 0
Gather: [ 2]: 1 1 1 1 1 1
Gather: [ 3]: 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: if I have 2 threads (per example) I would like T1 to get the content in sendbuff[0] and T2 the content in sendbuff[1]. I thought I was explaining myself good enough, sry :S

Comment: Neither scatter nor broadcast is going to do this, since you're excluding task 0, unless you do something like set up [intercommunicators](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node111.html), and even then, you'll have to change your allocation so that the sendbuff[]s are contiguous.

Comment: SO, why would I use scatter if I can't send to all my processes something as simple as an array of integers?

Comment: You can send to _all_ of them.  You're trying to send to a _subset_ of them.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to use intercommunicators to just scatter to / gather from the worker tasks.

Comment: ..alternately, of course, you can just pad the sendbuffer array with some fake data to send to task 0 and just use scatter (but make sure your data is allocated in a contiguous way).