# MPI Scatter for MPI Vector Type

Tags: mpi, scatter, multidimensional-array

I need to scatter a 3D Matrix(NxNxN). If it has to be done by cutting the z-dimension, then Scatter() works fine. I want to cut the matrix by y-dimension, ie, each process will receive N/NUM_PROCS x-z planes.

For this, I make a MPI Vector type which consists of N/NUM_PROCS x-z planes. But when I do MPI::Scatterv(), the data transferred to 0th process is correct while for others not!

Anyone knows any alternate for that? or why this approach is not working?

Comment: We'd need to see some (very small) code to understand what you're doing wrong. Can you put a couple of lines in to give us context?

Comment: If you look at the questions listed under "related" or search for similar terms on this site, you will see many similar questions.  They all come down to (a) to allocating the array to be contiguous, or (b) not resizing the type ( eg, http://stackoverflow.com/a/9271753/463827 ).  If one of those answers doesn't help, then, as @WesleyBland says, add some more information so others can offer more focussed suggestions.