# Error in MPI broadcast

Tags: mpi

Sorry for the long post. I did read some other MPI broadcast related errors but I couldn't
find out why my program is failing.
I am new to MPI and I am facing this problem. First I will explain what I am trying to do:

My declarations :
ROWTAG 400

COLUMNTAG 800

1. Create a 2 X 2 Cartesian topology.
2. Rank 0 has the whole matrix. It wants to dissipate parts of matrix to all the processes in the 2 X 2 Cartesian topology. For now, instead
   of matrix I am just dealing with integers. So for process P(i,j) in 2 X 2 Cartesian topology, (i - row , j - column), I want it to receive
   (ROWTAG + i ) in one message and (COLUMNTAG + j) in another message.
3. My strategy to do so is:
   Processes:  P(0,0) , P(0,1), P(1,0), P(1,1)

P(0,0) has all the initial data.

P(0,0) sends (ROWTAG+1) (in this case 401) to P(1,0)    -   In essense P(1,0) is responsible for dissipating information related to row 1 for all the processes in Row 1    -   I just used a blocking send

P(0,0) sends (COLUMNTAG+1) (in this case 801) to P(0,1) -   In essense P(0,1) is responsible for dissipating information related to column 1 for all the processes in Column 1 -    Used a blocking send

For each process, I made a row_group containing all the processes in that row and out of this created a row_comm (communicator object)

For each process, I made a col_group containing all the processes in that column and out of this created a col_comm (communicator object)

At this point, P(0,0) has given information related to row 'i' to Process P(i,0) and P(0,0) has given information related to column 'j' to 
P(0,j). I call P(i,0) and P(0,j) as row_head and col_head respectively.

For Process P(i,j) , P(i,0) gives information related to row i, and P(0,j) gives information related to column j.

I used a broad cast call:

```
MPI_Bcast(&row_data,1,MPI_INT,row_head,row_comm)
MPI_Bcast(&col_data,1,MPI_INT,col_head,col_comm)
```

Please find my code here: http://pastebin.com/NpqRWaWN

Here is the error I see:

*** An error occurred in MPI_Bcast**
 on communicator MPI COMMUNICATOR 5 CREATE FROM 3
 **MPI_ERR_ROOT: invalid root
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (your MPI job will now abort)

Also please let me know if there is any better way to distribute the matrix data.

Comment: Why are you reimplementing the functionality of `MPI_Cart_sub` instead of using it to partition the Cartesian communicator into row-wise and column-wise subcommunicators?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't know MPI_Cart_sub function existed. As I said, I am new to MPI.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your program. First, `row_Ranks` is declared with one element less and when writing to it, you possibly overwrite other stack variables:

```c
int col_Ranks[SIZE], row_Ranks[SIZE-1];
//                             ^^^^^^
```

On my test system the program just hangs because of that.

Second, you create new subcommunicators out of `matrixComm` but you use rank numbers from the latter to address processes in the former when performing the broadcast. That doesn't work. For example, in a 2x2 Cartesian communicator ranks range from 0 to 3. In any column- or row-wise subgroup there are only two processes with ranks 0 and 1 - there is neither rank 2 nor rank 3. If you take a look at the value of `row_head` across the ranks, it is `2` in two of them, hence the error.

For a much better way to distribute the data, you should refer to [this extremely informative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9271753/1374437).