# How do I use MPI to scatter a 2d array?

Tags: c, arrays, mpi, multidimensional-array

I am trying to use MPI to distribute the work for bucket sort. When I scatter the array, I wanted each process to receive a single bucket (int array) and be able to print its content. However, my current program prints out incorrect values, which make me think I am not indexing into the memory I want. Can someone help explain how I can properly index into the array I am passing to each process or how I am doing this incorrectly?

```
#define MAX_VALUE 64
#define N 32
main(int argc, char *argv[]){

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);  //initialize MPI environment
int** sendArray = malloc(16*sizeof(int *));
int *arrayIndex = (int *) malloc(16*sizeof(int));
int *receiveArray = (int *) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
int nps, myrank;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nps);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
int i;

if(myrank == 0)
{
  //create an array that stores the number of values in each bucket
  for( i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    arrayIndex[i] = 0;
  }

  int bucket =0;
  int temp = 0;
  //creates an int array within each array index of sendArray
  for( i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    sendArray[i] =  (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
  }
  //Create a random int array with values ranging from 0 to MAX_VALUE
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    temp= rand() % MAX_VALUE;
    bucket = temp/4;
    printf("assigning %d to index [%d][%d]\n", temp, bucket, arrayIndex[bucket]);
    sendArray[bucket][arrayIndex[bucket]]= temp;
    arrayIndex[bucket] = arrayIndex[bucket] + 1;
  }

 MPI_Scatter(sendArray, 16, MPI_INT, receiveArray, N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(arrayIndex, 16, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("bucket %d has %d values\n", myrank, arrayIndex[myrank]);
for( i = 0; i < arrayIndex[myrank]; i++){
  printf("bucket %d index %d has value %d\n", myrank, i, receiveArray[i]);

}
}
```

Comment: 2D arrays that are implemented as an array of pointers do not work with MPI. You should use a contiguous (flat) array storage, e.g. `sendArray = malloc(16 * N * sizeof(int));`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sending blocks of 2D array in C using MPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269399/sending-blocks-of-2d-array-in-c-using-mpi)

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do doesn't work because MPI always sends only the data you point to. It does not follow the pointers in your `sendArray`.

In your example you could just make your SendArray bigger, namely `16 * N` and put all your data into that continuous array. That way you have a one-dimensional array, but that should not be a Problem in the code you gave us because all buckets have the same length, so you can access element `j` from bucket `i` with `sendArray[i * N + j]`.

Also, in most cases `send_count` should be equal to `recv_count`. In your case that would be `N`. The correct MPI call would be

```
MPI_Scatter(sendArray, N, MPI_INT, receiveArray, N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```