# How to use MPI_Gatherv for collecting strings of diiferent length from different processor including master node?

Tags: c, arrays, parallel-processing, mpi

I am trying to collect different strings of different length from all processors (including the master node) into a single string (array of characters) at the master node. Here is the prototype for MPI_Gatherv:

```
int MPI_Gatherv(const void *sendbuf, int sendcount, MPI_Datatype sendtype,
            void *recvbuf, const int *recvcounts, const int *displs,
            MPI_Datatype recvtype, int root, MPI_Comm comm)**.
```

I am unable to define some parameters like `recvbuf`,`recvcounts` and `displs`. Could any one provide source code  example in C for this?

Comment: There are some examples of using [`MPI_Gatherv()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Gatherv.html) on the [mpi-forum](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node70.html). You can call `MPI_Gather()` to gather the length of each string from each process in in the array `recvcounts`, compute the displacements as `displs[0]=0, displs[i]=displs[i-1]+recvcounts[i-1]`, allocate enough space for `recvbuf`, call `MPI_Gatherv()` and finally set the null terminating character of  `recvbuf` to ensure a valid printable string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As has been pointed out, there are lots of examples of using `MPI_Gatherv`, including here on stack overflow; an answer which starts off describing how scatter and gather work, and then how the scatterv/gatherv variants extend that, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269399/sending-blocks-of-2d-array-in-c-using-mpi/9271753#9271753).

Crucially, for the simpler Gather operation, where every chunk is of the same size, the MPI library can easily precompute where each chunk should go in the final compiled array; in the more general gatherv operation, where this is less clear, you have the option - in fact, the requirement - to spell out exactly where each item should start.

The only extra complication here is that you're dealing with strings, so you probably don't want everything shoved right together; you'll want extra padding for spaces, and of course a null terminator at the end.

So let's say you have five processes wanting to send strings:

```
Rank 0: "Hello"    (len=5)
Rank 1: "world!"   (len=6)
Rank 2: "Bonjour"  (len=7)
Rank 3: "le"       (len=2)
Rank 4: "monde!"   (len=6)
```

You'll want this to be assembled into a global string:

```
Hello world! Bonjour le monde!\0
          111111111122222222223
0123456789012345678901234567890

recvcounts={5,6,7,2,6};  /* just the lengths */
displs = {0,6,13,21,24}; /* cumulative sum of len+1 for padding */
```

You can see that displacement 0 is 0, and displacement i is equal to the sum of (recvcounts[j]+1) for j=0..i-1:

```
   i    count[i]   count[i]+1   displ[i]   displ[i]-displ[i-1]
   ------------------------------------------------------------
   0       5          6           0    
   1       6          7           6                 6
   2       7          8          13                 7
   3       2          3          21                 8
   4       6          7          24                 3
```

And that's straightforwardly implemented:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define nstrings 5
const char *const strings[nstrings] = {"Hello","world!","Bonjour","le","monde!"};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 

    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    /* Everyone gets a string */    

    int myStringNum = rank % nstrings;
    char *mystring = (char *)strings[myStringNum];
    int mylen = strlen(mystring);

    printf("Rank %d: %s\n", rank, mystring);

    /*
     * Now, we Gather the string lengths to the root process, 
     * so we can create the buffer into which we'll receive the strings
     */

    const int root = 0;
    int *recvcounts = NULL;

    /* Only root has the received data */
    if (rank == root)
        recvcounts = malloc( size * sizeof(int)) ;

    MPI_Gather(&mylen, 1, MPI_INT,
               recvcounts, 1, MPI_INT,
               root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    /*
     * Figure out the total length of string, 
     * and displacements for each rank 
     */

    int totlen = 0;
    int *displs = NULL;
    char *totalstring = NULL;

    if (rank == root) {
        displs = malloc( size * sizeof(int) );

        displs[0] = 0;
        totlen += recvcounts[0]+1;

        for (int i=1; i<size; i++) {
           totlen += recvcounts[i]+1;   /* plus one for space or \0 after words */
           displs[i] = displs[i-1] + recvcounts[i-1] + 1;
        }

        /* allocate string, pre-fill with spaces and null terminator */
        totalstring = malloc(totlen * sizeof(char));            
        for (int i=0; i<totlen-1; i++)
            totalstring[i] = ' ';
        totalstring[totlen-1] = '\0';
    }

    /* 
     * Now we have the receive buffer, counts, and displacements, and 
     * can gather the strings 
     */

    MPI_Gatherv(mystring, mylen, MPI_CHAR,
                totalstring, recvcounts, displs, MPI_CHAR,
                root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    if (rank == root) {
        printf("%d: <%s>\n", rank, totalstring);
        free(totalstring);
        free(displs);
        free(recvcounts);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Running gives:

```
$ mpicc -o gatherstring gatherstring.c -Wall -std=c99
$ mpirun -np 5 ./gatherstring
Rank 0: Hello
Rank 3: le
Rank 4: monde!
Rank 1: world!
Rank 2: Bonjour
0: <Hello world! Bonjour le monde!>
```

Answer (score 4):

`MPI_Gather+MPI_Gatherv` requires calculating displacement for all ranks which I find it unnecessary when your strings are of almost similar lengths. Instead, you can use `MPI_Allreduce+MPI_Gather` with padded receive buffers of strings. The padding is done based on the longest available string which is calculated using `MPI_Allreduce`. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int rank;
    int nranks;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nranks);

    srand(time(NULL) + rank);
    int my_len =  (rand() % 10) + 1; // str_len   \in [1, 9]
    int my_char = (rand() % 26) + 65; // str_char \in [65, 90] = [A, Z]

    char my_str[my_len + 1];
    memset(my_str, my_char, my_len);
    my_str[my_len] = '\0';
    printf("rank %d of %d has string=%s with size=%zu\n",
            rank, nranks, my_str, strlen(my_str));

    int max_len = 0;
    MPI_Allreduce(&my_len, &max_len, 1, 
                  MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 

    // + 1 for taking account of null pointer at the end ['\n']
    char *my_str_padded[max_len + 1]; 
    memset(my_str_padded, '\0', max_len + 1);
    memcpy(my_str_padded, my_str, my_len);

    char *all_str = NULL;
    if(!rank) {
        int all_len = (max_len + 1) * nranks;
        all_str = malloc(all_len * sizeof(char));   
        memset(all_str, '\0', all_len);
    }

    MPI_Gather(my_str_padded, max_len + 1, MPI_CHAR, 
                     all_str, max_len + 1, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(!rank) {
        char *str_idx = all_str;
        int rank_idx = 0;
        while(*str_idx) {
            printf("rank %d sent string=%s with size=%zu\n", 
                    rank_idx, str_idx, strlen(str_idx));
            str_idx = str_idx + max_len + 1;
            rank_idx++;
        }

    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return(0);  
}
```

Have in mind that there is a tradeoff between selecting `MPI_Gather+MPI_Gatherv` which uses displacement and `MPI_AllReduce+MPI_Gather` which sometimes uses padding, because the former requires more time for calculating the displacements and the latter requires more storage to align the receive buffers.

I have also benchmarked the two approaches with big string buffers and could not find any significant runtime difference.

Comment: You are comparing `MPI_Gather()+MPI_Gatherv()` (collect string lengths first, and then the strings) with `MPI_Allreduce()+MPI_Gather()` (get the max string length and then collect them) that requires extra memory for padding, and might crash (trying to send more data could lead to a buffer overflow). I have hard time believing your approach can be faster even if it does not crash.

Comment: I've benchamrked both approaches and yes I couldn't find any significant performance gain using `MPI_Allreduce+MPI_Gather`. About the extra memory, as long as the size of substrings are almost the same and you `memset` them , this approach yield similar runtime. There're cases that this might not be efficient, e.g., when substring sizes vary a lot.

Comment: So were you able to find (significant) performance improvement or not ?

Comment: From my test cases the `MPI_Allreduce+GatherGather` was 10 ms faster on average (~355.77ms) with substrings of size 1 MB and a little variation at the end to enforce different sizes. Also, we're skipping the `for-loop` for calculating displacement and ! I believe, there will be cases this answer works even better than `MPI_Gather + MPI_Gatherv`..