# MPI_Gather to char array

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to write a elaborate hello world program using MPI. The idea is that the root process sends a message to the other processes, which in turn sends a message to the root containing their process id. So I want to send several character arrays to the root process and eventually print it.

The problem is that I don't manage to collect all the messages into a variable in the root process. I only get compile errors or unwanted output. I feel like I'm making some basic error in manipulating the char arrays ... I'd be glad if you could help me out!

The code so far:

```
// Hello world using MPI
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    // Define useful global constants
    int my_id, root_process, num_procs, rc;
    MPI_Status status;
    char[] final_message;    // <---- How should I define final message? Can I do this in another way?

    // Let master process be process 0
    root_process = 0;

    // Now, replicate this process to create parallel processes:
    rc = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    // Find out MY process ID and how many processes were started:
    rc = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_id);
    rc = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);

    // Broadcast master's message to slaves
    char message1[20];
    strcpy(message1, "Hello, World!");
    rc = MPI_Bcast(&message1, 14, MPI_CHAR, root_process, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // TEST: Each slave now displays message1 along with which process it is.
    //printf("I'm process %i, the message is: %.13s \n",my_id,message1);

    // Now the master collects a return message from each slave, including the process ID.
    char message2[31];
    char message22[2];
    strcpy(message2, "Master, I'm process number ");// %i \n",&my_id ); //28
    sprintf(message22,"%d\n",my_id);
    strcat(message2,message22);
    rc = MPI_Gather(message2, 1, MPI_CHAR, final_message, 1, MPI_CHAR, root_process, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // Display the message collected by the master. 
    printf(final_message);

    // Close down this process
    rc = MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Did you see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890523/how-to-use-mpi-gatherv-for-collecting-strings-of-diiferent-length-from-different?

Comment: I suppose @Shinzuwa has a problem with the dynamic declaration of the arrays....since you are not sure about the maximum size of the *final_message*, try allocating a random maximum size(say 1K, 4K, 16K) to this array using malloc/calloc tricks and then gather the *message2* from all the other processes to the *root_process*. If the size of *message2* array is different in different processes use the above link for reference.

Comment: Instead of `%d` use `%4d`. That way all processes will transmit a message of the same size and the root should allocate an array of `num_procs*32+1` chars (32 is the length of `"Master, I'm process number XXXX\n"`). As the `\0` terminator is not part of the messages, you'll have to manually set it: `final_message[32*num_procs] = '\0';`. The second and fifth arguments to `MPI_Gather` should be the message length, i.e. 32, not 1.