# MPI_Gatherv Negative count error

Tags: c, arrays, mpi, mpich

I am writing a MPI program where I need to gather an array from every process to root process. I am using `MPI_Gatherv`(since arrays can have variable length) function for doing this, However, I keep getting `PMPI_Gatherv(455): Negative count` exception. Below is the code snippet which does this `MPI_Gatherv` call. I haven't posted the complete code as it is too big but I can add required parts of code if required.

```
double *errs;
int *rcounts, *displ;
printf("P:%d calling gather with count %d\n", p->rank, f->slice_size);
if (p->rank == 0) {
errs = (double*) malloc (sizeof(double) * NGRID);
rcounts = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int) * p->total); 
displ = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int) * p->total);

}
MPI_Gatherv(f->err, f->slice_size, MPI_DOUBLE,
    (void*) errs, rcounts, displ, 
    MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("P:%d done with gather\n", p->rank);
```

`f->err` represents the array the array that I am trying to send and `f->slice_size` is size of that array. First `printf` prints correct values on all 4 processes, however last `printf` executes on all processes except for process `0`.

I get below exception

```
P:0 calling gather with count 250
P:1 calling gather with count 250
P:1 done with gather
P:2 calling gather with count 250
P:2 done with gather
P:3 calling gather with count 250
P:3 done with gather
    [cli_0]: aborting job:
    Fatal error in PMPI_Gatherv:
    Invalid count, error stack:
    PMPI_Gatherv(547): MPI_Gatherv failed(sbuf=0x2588290, scount=0, MPI_DOUBLE, rbuf=0x2588a70, rcnts=0x2548750, displs=0x2546d90, MPI_DOUBLE, root=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
    PMPI_Gatherv(455): Negative count, value is -1908728888
```

Comment: rank 0 invokes `MPI_Gatherv()` with `count=0`, but you already printed `f->slice_size == 150` which is pretty odd. also, you did not post how you initialize `rcounts` nor `displs`, you should first print these values on rank 0. i do not think a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be too big, so feel free to build and post one.

Comment: can you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890523/how-to-use-mpi-gatherv-for-collecting-strings-of-diiferent-length-from-different ? i hope this will help you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet suggests some confusion about `MPI_Gatherv()` semantic.
`rcounts` and `displ` are input arguments that are use read-only by `MPI_Gatherv()`. These arrays must be properly initialized before `MPI_Gatherv()` is invoked. If the root rank does not know how much data will be sent by the other ranks, then some extra logic must be manually added in order to retrieve this information. `MPI_Gather()` can be used to retrieve `rcounts`, and then `displ` can be built from `rcounts`.

A somehow similar question was already asked and eloquently answered at [How to use MPI_Gatherv for collecting strings of diiferent length from different processor including master node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890523/how-to-use-mpi-gatherv-for-collecting-strings-of-diiferent-length-from-different)

Comment: Thanks, I realized that! Man page does not clearly mention that. Hence the confusion!