# MPI gathering 2D subarrays

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I know this has been answered many times before and there is a comprehensive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269399/sending-blocks-of-2d-array-in-c-using-mpi/9271753#9271753) which I have read and attempted to use but I just can't get my code to work for some reason.

I have stripped my code down a bit to make it a bit easier to follow, but basically what I am trying to do is have each process initialise a sub-array and work on it, then put the whole big array back together on rank 0. `MPI_Gatherv` is giving me a segfault and I cannot figure out why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#define N 32

void init_lattice(double **site, int row, int col){
  int i,j;
  for(i=0; i<row; i++){
    for(j=0; j<col; j++){
      site[i][j]=(drand48()/4294967295.0 + 0.5)*2*M_PI;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  int nprocs, rank;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);   

  int dim = 2;
  int grid[dim];
  grid[0]=0;
  grid[1]=0;

  // Assign the grid dimensions
  MPI_Dims_create(nprocs, dim, grid);
  printf("Dim grid: length: %d, width: %d\n", grid[0], grid[1]);
  // The new communicator
  MPI_Comm comm_grid;
  // Allow cyclic behavior
  int periodic[dim];
  periodic[0] = 1;
  periodic[1] = 1;
  
  // Create the communicator
  MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, dim, grid, periodic, 0, &comm_grid);

  int block_len, block_width;
  block_len = N/grid[1];
  block_width = N/grid[0];
 
  int i, j;
  //Create lattice subset
  double  *data   = (double  *) malloc (block_len * block_width * sizeof(double));
  double **site = (double **) malloc (block_len * sizeof(double *));
  for (i = 0; i < block_len; i++)
    site[i] = & (data[i * block_width]);

  //Initialise lattice
  init_lattice(site, block_len, block_width);

  MPI_Datatype newtype, subtype;

  int sizes[dim];
  sizes[0]=N;
  sizes[1]=N;

  int subsizes[dim];  
  subsizes[0] = block_len;
  subsizes[1] = block_width;

  int starts[dim];   
  starts[0] = 0;
  starts[1] = 0;  

  MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, sizes, subsizes, starts, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_DOUBLE, &newtype);
  MPI_Type_create_resized(newtype, 0, N/grid[1]*sizeof(double), &subtype);
  MPI_Type_commit(&subtype);

  int sendcounts[grid[0]*grid[1]];
  int displs[grid[0]*grid[1]];

  if (rank == 0) {
    for (i=0; i<grid[0]*grid[1]; i++) sendcounts[i] = 1;
    int disp = 0;
    for (i=0; i<grid[0]; i++) {
      for (j=0; j<grid[1]; j++) {
        displs[i*grid[0]+j] = disp;
        disp += 1;
      }
      disp += ((N/grid[1])-1)*grid[0];
    }
  }

  //Create global lattice
  double  *global_data   = (double  *) malloc (N * N * sizeof(double));
  double **global_site = (double **) malloc (N * sizeof(double *));
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    global_site[i] = & (global_data[i * N]);

  MPI_Gatherv(&(site[0][0]), N*N/(grid[0]*grid[1]),  MPI_DOUBLE, &(global_site[0][0]), sendcounts, displs, subtype, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if(rank==0){
    printf("Rank: %d\n", rank);
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
      for(j=0; j<N; j++){
        printf("%.2lf ", global_site[i][j]);  
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
Ok so I have changed my array allocations to contiguous memory and everything is working as it should now. Thanks talonmies!

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem here is that MPI expects all allocations to be contiguous blocks of memory. Your `site` and `global_site` arrays are not, they are arrays of pointers. The MPI routines are just reading past the end of each individual row allocation and causing your segfault.

If you want to allocate an `n x n` array to use with the MPI then you need to replace this:

```
  double **global_site;
  if(rank==0){
    global_site = malloc(sizeof(double *)*(N));
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
      global_site[i] = malloc(sizeof(double)*(N));
  }
```

with something like this:

```
  double *global_site = malloc(sizeof(double)*(N * N));
```

You will obviously need to adjust the rest of your code accordingly.

It seems the only reason you are actually using arrays of pointers is for the convenience of `[i][j]` style 2D indexing. If you use linear or pitched linear memory, you can easily make a little preprocessor macro or helper function which can give you that style of indexing into row or column major ordered storage which is still compatible with MPI.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have now changed the allocation of my arrays, however, I am still getting the same seg fault unfortunately..

Comment: Nevermind, I had another silly mistake in my code elsewhere as well. All working now, thank you!

Comment: @stroopy: To mark this question as answered, please consider accepting the answer. It improves visibility in search and might make it easier for the next person to find