# How to MPI_Gather a 2d array of structs with C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, mpi, mpich

I am trying to render a fractal calculated using MPI. I used the answer to the following question as reference: [sending blocks of 2D array in C using MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269399/sending-blocks-of-2d-array-in-c-using-mpi)

My problem is, that merge of data via `MPI_Gatherv` calculated by all the processes does not seem to work properly, because my main process always renders a black screen.

I have the following struct defined:

```
typedef struct Point {
    float r,g,b,x,y;
} Point;
```

In my main I try to create an MPI_Datatype for the struct:

```
MPI_Datatype struct_type;
MPI_Datatype struct_members[1] = {MPI_FLOAT};
MPI_Aint     offsets[1] = {0};
int          struct_blengths[1] = {5};
int struct_items = 1;
MPI_Type_create_struct(struct_items, struct_blengths, offsets, struct_members, &struct_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&struct_type);
```

I have a global variable for the calculation result:

```
Point **mandelbrot;
```

The variable is allocated thusly before each frame is being recalculated:

```
if (proc_id == root) {
    //Just a check if this is the first frame that is being rendered
    if (s > 0) {
        free(&(mandelbrot[0][0]));
        free(mandelbrot);
    }

    s = W;
    Point *p = (Point *) malloc(W * H * sizeof(Point));
    mandelbrot = (Point **) malloc(W*sizeof(Point *));
    for (int i = 0; i < W; i++) {
        mandelbrot[i] = &(p[i*H]);
    }
}
```

Here I try to create an array subtype using the `Point` struct (following the referenced answer as best I can):

```
//Width of the fractal to render
W = width;
//Height of the fractal
H = height;
//Chunk of width each process is responsible for [width / number of processes]
int segmentSize = (int) W / ntasks;

MPI_Datatype type, resizedtype;
int sizes[2]    = {W,H};  /* size of global array */
int subsizes[2] = {segmentSize, H};  /* size of sub-region */
int starts[2]   = {0,0};
MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, sizes, subsizes, starts, MPI_ORDER_C, struct_type, &type);
MPI_Type_create_resized(type, 0, H*sizeof(Point), &resizedtype);
MPI_Type_commit(&resizedtype);
```

Calculate the displacements and counts of blocks to send and allocate memory for the process' subarray:

```
int sendcounts[segmentSize*H];
int displs[segmentSize*H];

if (proc_id == root) {
    for (int i=0; i<segmentSize*H; i++) sendcounts[i] = 1;
    int disp = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<segmentSize; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<H; j++) {
            displs[i*H+j] = disp;
            disp += 1;
        }
        disp += ((W/segmentSize)-1)*H;
    }
}

Point *p = (Point *) malloc(segmentSize * H * sizeof(Point));

Point **segment;
segment = (Point **) malloc(segmentSize * sizeof(Point*));
for (int i = 0; i < segmentSize; i++) {
    segment[i] = &(p[i*H]);
}
```

Following that I calculate the color of the Mandelbrot set for each point in the chunk:

```
    int i;
    float c[3], dX, dY;
    for ( x = 0; x < segmentSize; x++) {
         for ( y = 0; y < H; y++) {
            //Iterate over the point
            i = iterateMandelbrot(rM + x * dR, iM - y * dI);
            // Get decimal coordinates for rendering <0,1>
            dX = (x + segmentSize * proc_id) / W;
            dY = y / H;
            //Calculate color using Bernoulli Polynomials
            makeColor(i, maxIterations, c);
            segment[x][y].x = (float) dX;
            segment[x][y].y = (float) dY;
            segment[x][y].r = (float) c[0];
            segment[x][y].g = (float) c[1];
            segment[x][y].b = (float) c[2];
         }
    }
```

Lastly I try to gather the chunks into the `mandelbort` variable for the root process to render:

```
int buffsize = (int) segmentSize * H;

MPI_Gatherv(&(segment[0][0]), W*H/(buffsize), struct_type,
             &(mandelbrot[0][0]), sendcounts, displs, resizedtype,
             root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Type_free(&resizedtype);
```

Ok so the problem is now that no data seems to be written into the `mandelbrot` variable as my main process renders a black screen. Without using MPI the code works so the problem lies somewhere in the `MPI_Gatherv` call or maybe the way I am allocating the arrays. I realize there might be some memory leak associated with the mandelbrot set or the local `segment` arrays but that is not my main concern at the moment. Can you see what I am doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It would be much easier to help you, if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: You are providing false block information to `MPI_Gatherv`. `sendcounts` and `displs` must have `ntasks` elements, not `segmentSize*H` (which is equal to `W * H / ntasks`) - one element per MPI rank. You should provide in `displs` the offset of the beginning of each sub-block, not of each line of each sub-block.