# Need or not to allocate whole domain grid

Tags: c, mpi

I have coded a small application which solves a partial equation with MPI library.

For each MPI rank, I allocate the whole grid domain to solve. The code is structured like this :

1. Allocate global array for whole domain
2. Define neighbours with `MPI_Cart_shift`
3. Calculate coordinates `(xs,ys)` (starting) and `(xe,ye)` (ending) of subdomains (on the grid) for the current MPI rank called "me"
4. Update the boundaries for current MPI rank
5. Enter into the main loop :

```
// Main loop 
while(!convergence)
{
    step = step + 1;
    t = t + dt ;

    /* Perform one step of the explicit scheme */
    Explicit(x0, x, dt, &resLoc, hx, hy, me, xs, ys, xe, ye, k0);

    /* Update the partial solution along the interface */
    updateBound(x0, NeighBor, comm2d, column_type, me, xs, ys, xe, ye, xcell);

    /* Reduce all cartesian subgrids for convergence */
    MPI_Allreduce(&resLoc, &result, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, comm);

    result= sqrt(result);

    if ((result<epsilon) || (step>maxStep)) break;
}
```

Code remains into the main loop until convergence is reached. Into `Explicit`, I compute the next values for current iteration. Then, I update the deges of each sub-domains and I sen/receive them to neighbours.

Finally, I compute the by doing a reduction the error as a respect of convergence value of current iteration.

If error is smaller than defined convergence (`result < epsilon`), then I break from this main loop.

6. Afterwards, I gather all sub-domains in a final array `xfinal` by doing :

```
MPI_Gather(xtemp,xcell*ycell, MPI_DOUBLE, xfinal, xcell*ycell, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, comm);
```

Then, I print the solution (`xfinal` array) into output file.

My question is that  don't know how to avoid to allocate a whole domain array for each MPI rank : indeed, if size of 2D domain is very high, one may not have enough RAM memory on each single node to allocate the two 2D arrays that I use (`x[i][j]` and `x0[i][j]`).

I don't know if it is possible to allocate just one sub-domain per MPI process : but in this case, how to communicate between them ? I need a whole domain to send and receive the lines/columns between processes, don't I ?

If someone could help me and tell me if it is possible to just allocate a sub-domain for each MPI rank ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way to allocate the sub-domains and exchange information between them is right there on your figure. Initially populating the sub-domains via scatter and then collection of the full solution via gather could be implemented as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9271753/1374437).

Comment: This is exactly what is depicted on the picture. One column or row from each domain gets transferred to the neighbouring process into the so-called halo region. It has to be done at the beginning of each iteration and is called "halo exchange" or "ghost cells" pattern. Just look it up on the Internet - there are literally thousands of code examples.