# MPI sending 2D array

Tags: multidimensional-array, graph, mpi, breadth-first-search

I am new to MPI. I am trying to assign an adjacency matrix to the processes so that I am able to implement the 1-D BFS algorithm given by https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1559977. Assume that I have a 6*6 matrix like that with 4 processes:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 1
```

I want it to be processed like:

```
A A A A A A
B B B B B B
C C C C C C
D D D D D D
D D D D D D
D D D D D D
```

That every process is assigned with `(int)(no_of_vertices/size)` number of rows and the last process is assigned with the rest of the rows which equals to `(no_of_vertices-(size-1)*local_vertices)` **since the graph size will hardly be evenly divisible by the number of processes p that every process has the same workload**.
Therefore, I read through this answer by Jonathan Dursi [sending blocks of 2D array in C using MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269399/sending-blocks-of-2d-array-in-c-using-mpi) and have my own code. I post it below:

```cpp
    #include "mpi.h"
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    
    #define MAX_QUEUE_SIZE 5
    
    
    int Max(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        int max;
        if (a >= b)
        {
            if (a >= c) {
                max = a;
            }
            else
                max = c;
        }
        else if (b >= c) { max = b; }
        else max = c;
        return max;
    }
    
    int areAllVisited(int visited[], int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (visited[i] == 0)
                return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    int malloc2dint(int*** array, int n, int m) {
    
        /* allocate the n*m contiguous items */
        int* p = (int*)malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
        if (!p) return -1;
    
        /* allocate the row pointers into the memory */
        (*array) = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
        if (!(*array)) {
            free(p);
            return -1;
        }
    
        /* set up the pointers into the contiguous memory */
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            (*array)[i] = &(p[i * m]);
    
        return 0;
    }
    int free2dint(int*** array) {
        /* free the memory - the first element of the array is at the start */
        free(&((*array)[0][0]));
    
        /* free the pointers into the memory */
        free(*array);
    
        return 0;
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        //Variables and Initializations
        int size, rank;
        int local_vertices;
        int** adj_matrix=NULL;
        int *adjacency_matrix;
        int adjacency_queue[MAX_QUEUE_SIZE];
        int source_vertex;
        int no_of_vertices;
    int ** local_adj_matrix;
        int *visited;
        int *distance;
        int* frontier_vertex;
        //MPI Code
    
    
    
        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); // MPI_COMM -> communicator, size=number of processes
           // Get my rank in the communicator
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);//rank= current processes
        //read input file, transform into adjacency matrix
        
        if (rank == 0)
        {       
            string filename="out.txt";
            std::fstream in(filename.c_str());
            cout << "reading file:" << filename << endl;
            string s;
            size_t n = 0, m = 0;
            string data1, data2;
            while (true)
            {
                std::getline(in, s);
                istringstream is(s);
                is >> data1 >> data2;
                int d1 = stoi(data1);
                int d2 = stoi(data2);
                n = Max(n, d2, d1);
                m += 1;
                if (in.eof()) { break; }
            }
            //this block will count the number of lines and calculate the maximun number appeared in the file, which are the parameters n, m(vertice, edge)
            in.clear();
            in.seekg(0, ios::beg);
            n += 1;
            m -= 1;
    
            //initialize the 2D array
    malloc2dint(&adj_matrix, n, n);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    adj_matrix[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
            for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                int x, y;
                std::getline(in, s);
                istringstream is(s);
                is >> data1 >> data2;
                x = stoi(data1);
                y = stoi(data2);
                adj_matrix[x][y] = 1;
    
            }
            in.close();
            //print the matrix
            cout << "the adjacency matrix is:" << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                cout << endl;
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    cout << adj_matrix[i][j] << " ";
                }
            }
    
            source_vertex = 0;
            no_of_vertices = n;
        local_vertices = (int)(no_of_vertices/size);
    
        }   
        MPI_Bcast(&local_vertices,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(&no_of_vertices, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);      
        MPI_Bcast(&source_vertex, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        /* create a datatype to describe the subarrays of the global array */
        int sizes[2] = { no_of_vertices, no_of_vertices };         /* global size */
        int subsizes[2] = { 1, no_of_vertices };     /* local size */
        int starts[2] = { 0,0 };                        /* where this one starts */
        MPI_Datatype type, subarrtype;
        MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, sizes, subsizes, starts, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_INT, &type);
        MPI_Type_create_resized(type, 0, no_of_vertices * sizeof(int), &subarrtype);// /local_vertices
        MPI_Type_commit(&subarrtype);
        if (rank == size - 1) {
            local_vertices = no_of_vertices - (size - 1) * local_vertices;
            malloc2dint(&local_adj_matrix, local_vertices, no_of_vertices); }
        malloc2dint(&local_adj_matrix,local_vertices,no_of_vertices);
        //MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        int* adjptr = NULL;
        if (rank == 0) adjptr = &(adj_matrix[0][0]);
        int *sendcounts=new int[size];
        int *displs = new int[size];
    
        if (rank == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
                if (i == size - 1) {
                    sendcounts[i] = no_of_vertices - (size - 1) * local_vertices;
                }
                else
                sendcounts[i] = local_vertices;
            int disp = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    displs[i] = disp;
                    disp += no_of_vertices*local_vertices;
            }
        }
    
        //Scattering each row of the adjacency matrix to each of the processes
        //int MPI_Scatter(const void* sendbuf, int sendcount, MPI_Datatype sendtype,void* recvbuf, int recvcount, MPI_Datatype recvtype, int root, MPI_Comm comm)
        MPI_Scatterv(adjptr, sendcounts,displs,subarrtype, &local_adj_matrix[0][0], local_vertices*no_of_vertices, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
            cout << "rank=" << rank << endl;
            for(int i=0;i<local_vertices;i++){
                cout << endl;
                for (int j = 0; j < no_of_vertices; j++) {
                cout << local_adj_matrix[i][j] << " ";
            }
        }
    
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        //End of BFS code
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }
```

However, the situation in [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269399/sending-blocks-of-2d-array-in-c-using-mpi) is not the same as mine and naturally, I got the unexpected outputs:

```
reading file:out.txt
the adjacency matrix is:

0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
rank=1

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 rank=0

rank=2
rank=4


rank=3

rank=5

rank=6
rank=7


0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
-410582944 556 -410582944 556 -410353664 556 815104 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -912406441 -1879044864
0 0 0 0 0 0 -906966900 -1879046144 -410511728 556 -410398928 556
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
-33686019 2949222 32575338 37898 -410536560 556 -410396256 556 3473509 6357044 8192057 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\mpiexec.exe (process 3628) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

I am sure that there are huge mistakes in my initialization of the two arrays `sendcounts` and `displs` and the creation of the `newtype subarrtype` but I have no idea how to fix them. Anyone give me some hands?

possible input file:

```
0 3
0 2
2 3
3 1
5 11
5 4
5 1
6 10
8 5
9 4
10 4
11 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined a subarray that maps on to all the local data you want to send, all the sendcounts should be 1. The receive counts need to be the number of integers in the message (which is what you seem to have set them as) but the send count is one subarray.

Comment: Thanks, bro. I tried, but it is still not working. I assume there must be something else like I resize it wrong or assigned it wrong. I also update my input file in the description. Could you please have a test?

Answer (score 0):

Just as sendcounts is in terms of sizeof(dataype), so are the displacements. If you edit line 186:

> ```
> disp += no_of_vertices*local_vertices;
> ```

to be:

> ```
> disp += local_vertices;
> ```

then I think it works.

You actually don't need all the complications of resized dataytypes as you are scattering complete, contiguous rows.