# Sending 2D arrays in Fortran with MPI_Gather

Tags: fortran, mpi

I want to send 2d chunks of data using `MPI_GATHER`. For example: I have 2x3 arrays on each node and I want 8x3 array on root, if I have 4 nodes. For 1d arrays, `MPI_GATHER` sorts data according to MPI ranks, but for 2d data it creates a mess!

What is the clean way to put chunks in order?

I expected the output of this code:

```
program testmpi
  use mpi
  implicit none
  integer :: send (2,3)
  integer :: rec (4,3)
  integer :: ierror,my_rank,i,j

  call MPI_Init(ierror)
  MPI_DATA_TYPE type_col
  ! find out process rank
  call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_rank, ierror)
  if (my_rank==0) then
    send=1
    do i=1,2
      print*,(send(i,j),j=1,3)
    enddo
  endif
  if (my_rank==1) then
    send=5
    ! do 1,2
    !   print*,(send(i,j),j=1,3)
    ! enddo
  endif
  call MPI_GATHER(send,6,MPI_INTEGER,rec,6,MPI_INTEGER,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)
  if (my_rank==0) then
    print*,'<><><><><>rec'
    do i=1,4
      print*,(rec(i,j),j=1,3)
    enddo
  endif
  call MPI_Finalize(ierror)
end program testmpi
```

to be something like this :

```
   1           1           1
   1           1           1
   5           5           5
   5           5           5
```

but it looks like this:

```
   1           1           5
   1           1           5
   1           5           5
   1           5           5
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9271753/463827) gives code for C, but the basic ideas are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your fast replay. I edited the question and add an example to clarify my problem. The answer was a bit unclear for me. What should I do step by step? I guess some steps in that answer is only for C, because lack of native multidimensional array support.

Comment: The basic ideas are the same.  You need to (a) understand how memory is laid out in the multid array; (b) create a derived type to describe the block of data you're sending; (c) use extents to describe where your data is going.

Answer (score 34):

The following a literal Fortran translation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9271753/463827). I had thought this was unnecessary, but the multiple differences in array indexing and memory layout might mean that it is worth doing a Fortran version.

Let me start by saying that you generally don't really want to do this - scatter and gather huge chunks of data from some "master" process. Normally you want each task to be chugging away at its own piece of the puzzle, and you should aim to never have one processor need a "global view" of the whole data; as soon as you require that, you limit scalability and the problem size. If you're doing this for I/O - one process reads the data, then scatters it, then gathers it back for writing, you'll want eventually to look into MPI-IO.

Getting to your question, though, MPI has very nice ways of pulling arbitrary data out of memory, and scatter/gathering it to and from a set of processors. Unfortunately that requires a fair number of MPI concepts - MPI Types, extents, and collective operations. A lot of the basic ideas are discussed in the answer to this question -- [MPI_Type_create_subarray and MPI_Gather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585630/mpi-type-create-subarray-and-mpi-gather) .

Consider a 1d integer global array that task 0 has that you want to distribute to a number of MPI tasks, so that they each get a piece in their local array. Say you have 4 tasks, and the global array is [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. You could have task 0 send four messages (including one to itself) to distribute this, and when it's time to re-assemble, receive four messages to bundle it back together; but that obviously gets very time consuming at large numbers of processes. There are optimized routines for these sorts of operations - scatter/gather operations. So in this 1d case you'd do something like this:

```
integer, dimension(8) :: global      ! only root has this
integer, dimension(2) :: local       ! everyone has this
integer, parameter    :: root = 0
integer :: rank, comsize
integer :: i, ierr

call MPI_Init(ierr)
call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, comsize, ierr)
call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)

if (rank == root) then
    global = [ (i, i=1,8) ]
endif

call MPI_Scatter(global, 2, MPI_INTEGER, &    ! send everyone 2 ints from global
                 local,  2, MPI_INTEGER, &    ! each proc recieves 2 into
                 root,                   &    ! sending process is root,
                 MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)        ! all procs in COMM_WORLD participate
```

After this, the processors' data would look like

```
task 0:  local:[1,2]  global: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
task 1:  local:[3,4]  global: [garbage]
task 2:  local:[5,6]  global: [garbage]
task 3:  local:[7,8]  global: [garbage]
```

That is, the scatter operation takes the global array and sends contiguous 2-int chunks to all the processors.

To re-assemble the array, we use the MPI_Gather() operation, which works exactly the same but in reverse:

```
local = local + rank

call MPI_Gather (local,  2, MPI_INTEGER, &    ! everyone sends 2 ints from local
                 global, 2, MPI_INTEGER, &    ! root receives 2 ints each proc into global
                 root,                   &    ! receiving process is root,
                 MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)        ! all procs in COMM_WORLD participate
```

And now the arrays look like:

```
task 0:  local:[1,2]    global: [1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11]
task 1:  local:[4,5]    global: [garbage-]
task 2:  local:[7,8]    global: [garbage-]
task 3:  local:[10,11]  global: [garbage-]
```

Gather brings all the data back.

What happens if the number of data points doesn't evenly divide the number of processes, and we need to send different numbers of items to each process? Then you need a generalized version of scatter, [`MPI_Scatterv`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Scatterv.html), which lets you specify the counts for each processor, and displacements -- where in the global array that piece of data starts. So let's say with the same 4 tasks you had an array of characters [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i] with 9 characters, and you were going to assign every process two characters except the last, that got three. Then you'd need

```
character, dimension(9) :: global
character, dimension(3) :: local
integer, dimension(4)   :: counts
integer, dimension(4)   :: displs

if (rank == root) then
    global = [ (achar(i+ichar('a')), i=0,8) ]
endif
local = ['-','-','-']

counts = [2,2,2,3]
displs = [0,2,4,6]

mycounts = counts(rank+1)

call MPI_Scatterv(global, counts, displs,         & ! proc i gets counts(i) chars from displs(i)
                  MPI_CHARACTER,                  &
                  local, mycounts, MPI_CHARACTER, & ! I get mycounts chars into
                  root,                           & ! root rank does sending
                  MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)             ! all procs in COMM_WORLD participate
```

Now the data looks like

```
task 0:  local:"ab-"  global: "abcdefghi"
task 1:  local:"cd-"  global: *garbage*
task 2:  local:"ef-"  global: *garbage*
task 3:  local:"ghi"  global: *garbage*
```

You've now used scatterv to distribute the irregular amounts of data. The displacement in each case is two*rank (measured in characters; the displacement is in unit of the types being sent for a scatter or received for a gather; it's not generally in bytes or something) from the start of the array, and the counts are [2,2,2,3]. If it had been the first processor we wanted to have 3 characters, we would have set counts=[3,2,2,2] and displacements would have been [0,3,5,7]. Gatherv again works exactly the same but reverse; the counts and displs arrays would remain the same.

Now, for 2D, this is a bit trickier. If we want to send 2d sublocks of a 2d array, the data we're sending now no longer is contiguous. If we're sending (say) 3x3 subblocks of a 6x6 array to 4 processors, the data we're sending has holes in it:

```
2D Array

   ---------
   |000|222|
   |000|222|
   |000|222|
   |---+---|
   |111|333|
   |111|333|
   |111|333|
   ---------

Actual layout in memory

   [000111000111000111222333222333222333]
```

(Note that all high-performance computing comes down to understanding the layout of data in memory.)

If we want to send the data that is marked "1" to task 1, we need to skip three values, send three values, skip three values, send three values, skip three values, send three values. A second complication is where the subregions stop and start; note that region "1" doesn't start where region "0" stops; after the last element of region "0", the next location in memory is partway-way through region "1".

Let's tackle the first layout problem first - how to pull out just the data we want to send. We could always just copy out all the "0" region data to another, contiguous array, and send that; if we planned it out carefully enough, we could even do that in such a way that we could call MPI_Scatter on the results. But we'd rather not have to transpose our entire main data structure that way.

So far, all the MPI data types we've used are simple ones - MPI_INTEGER specifies (say) 4 bytes in a row. However, MPI lets you create your own data types that describe arbitrarily complex data layouts in memory. And this case -- rectangular subregions of an array -- is common enough that [there's a specific call for that](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Type_create_subarray.html). For the 2-dimensional case we're describing above,

```
integer :: newtype;
integer, dimension(2) :: sizes, subsizes, starts

sizes    = [6,6]     ! size of global array
subsizes = [3,3]     ! size of sub-region 
starts   = [0,0]     ! let's say we're looking at region "0"
                     ! which begins at offset [0,0] 

call MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, sizes, subsizes, starts, MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_INTEGER, newtype, ierr)
call MPI_Type_commit(newtype, ierr)
```

This creates a type which picks out just the region "0" from the global array.  Note that even in Fortran, the start parameter is given as an *offset* (eg, 0-based) from the start of the array, not an index (eg, 1-based).

We could send just that piece of data now to another processor

```
call MPI_Send(global, 1, newtype, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)  ! send region "0"
```

and the receiving process could receive it into a local array. Note that the receiving process, if it's only receiving it into a 3x3 array, can not describe what it's receiving as a type of newtype; that no longer describes the memory layout, because there aren't big skips between the end of one row and the start of the next. Instead, it's just receiving a block of 3*3 = 9 integers:

```
call MPI_Recv(local, 3*3, MPI_INTEGER, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
```

Note that we could do this for other sub-regions, too, either by creating a different type (with different start array) for the other blocks, or just by sending starting from the first location of the particular block:

```
if (rank == root) then
    call MPI_Send(global(4,1), 1, newtype, 1, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    call MPI_Send(global(1,4), 1, newtype, 2, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    call MPI_Send(global(4,4), 1, newtype, 3, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    local = global(1:3, 1:3)
else
    call MPI_Recv(local, 3*3, MPI_INTEGER, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, rstatus, ierr)
endif
```

Now that we understand how to specify subregions, there's only one more thing to discuss before using scatter/gather operations, and that's the "size" of these types. We couldn't just use MPI_Scatter() (or even scatterv) with these types yet, because these types have an extent of 15 integers; that is, where they end is 15 integers after they start -- and where they end doesn't line up nicely with where the next block begins, so we can't just use scatter - it would pick the wrong place to start sending data to the next processor.

Of course, we could use MPI_Scatterv() and specify the displacements ourselves, and that's what we'll do - except the displacements are in units of the send-type size, and that doesn't help us either; the blocks start at offsets of (0,3,18,21) integers from the start of the global array, and the fact that a block ends 15 integers from where it starts doesn't let us express those displacements in integer multiples at all.

To deal with this, MPI lets you set the extent of the type for the purposes of these calculations. It doesn't truncate the type; it's just used for figuring out where the next element starts given the last element. For types like these with holes in them, it's frequently handy to set the extent to be something smaller than the distance in memory to the actual end of the type.

We can set the extent to be anything that's convenient to us. We could just make the extent 1 integer, and then set the displacements in units of integers. In this case, though, I like to set the extent to be 3 integers - the size of a sub-column - that way, block "1" starts immediately after block "0", and block "3" starts immediately after block "2". Unfortunately, it doesn't quite work as nicely when jumping from block "2" to block "3", but that can't be helped.

So to scatter the subblocks in this case, we'd do the following:

```
integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: extent

starts   = [0,0]
sizes    = [6, 6]
subsizes = [3, 3]

call MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, sizes, subsizes, starts,        &
                              MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_INTEGER,  &
                              newtype, ierr)
call MPI_Type_size(MPI_INTEGER, intsize, ierr)
extent = 3*intsize
call MPI_Type_create_resized(newtype, 0, extent, resizedtype, ierr)
call MPI_Type_commit(resizedtype, ierr)
```

Here we've created the same block type as before, but we've resized it; we haven't changed where the type "starts" (the 0) but we've changed where it "ends" (3 integers). We didn't mention this before, but the `MPI_Type_commit` is required to be able to use the type; but you only need to commit the final type you actually use, not any intermediate steps. You use `MPI_Type_free` to free the committed type when you're done.

So now, finally, we can scatterv the blocks: the data manipulations above are a little complicated, but once it's done, the scatterv looks just like before:

```
counts = 1          ! we will send one of these new types to everyone
displs = [0,1,6,7]  ! the starting point of everyone's data
                    ! in the global array, in block extents

call MPI_Scatterv(global, counts, displs, & ! proc i gets counts(i) types from displs(i) 
        resizedtype,                      &
        local, 3*3, MPI_INTEGER,          & ! I'm receiving 3*3 int
        root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)         !... from (root, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
```

And now we're done, after a little tour of scatter, gather, and MPI derived types.

An example code which shows both the gather and the scatter operation, with character arrays, follows. Running the program:

```
$ mpirun -np 4 ./scatter2d
 global array is:
 000222
 000222
 000222
 111333
 111333
 111333
 Rank            0  received:
 000
 000
 000
 Rank            1  received:
 111
 111
 111
 Rank            2  received:
 222
 222
 222
 Rank            3  received:
 333
 333
 333
 Rank            0  sending:
 111
 111
 111
 Rank            1  sending:
 222
 222
 222
 Rank            2  sending:
 333
 333
 333
 Rank            3  sending:
 444
 444
 444
  Root received:
 111333
 111333
 111333
 222444
 222444
 222444
```

and the code follows:

```
program scatter
    use mpi
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: gridsize = 6    ! size of array
    integer, parameter :: procgridsize = 2 ! size of process grid
    character, allocatable, dimension (:,:) :: global, local
    integer, dimension(procgridsize**2)   :: counts, displs
    integer, parameter    :: root = 0
    integer :: rank, comsize
    integer :: localsize
    integer :: i, j, row, col, ierr, p, charsize
    integer, dimension(2) :: sizes, subsizes, starts

    integer :: newtype, resizedtype
    integer, parameter :: tag = 1
    integer, dimension(MPI_STATUS_SIZE) :: rstatus
    integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: extent, begin

    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, comsize, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)

    if (comsize /= procgridsize**2) then
        if (rank == root) then
            print *, 'Only works with np = ', procgridsize**2, ' for now.'
        endif
        call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
        stop
    endif

    localsize = gridsize/procgridsize
    allocate( local(localsize, localsize) )
    if (rank == root) then
        allocate( global(gridsize, gridsize) )
        forall( col=1:procgridsize, row=1:procgridsize )
            global((row-1)*localsize+1:row*localsize, &
                   (col-1)*localsize+1:col*localsize) = &
                    achar(ichar('0')+(row-1)+(col-1)*procgridsize)
        end forall

        print *, 'global array is: '
        do i=1,gridsize
            print *, global(i,:)
        enddo
    endif
    starts   = [0,0]
    sizes    = [gridsize, gridsize]
    subsizes = [localsize, localsize]

    call MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, sizes, subsizes, starts,        &
                                  MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_CHARACTER,  &
                                  newtype, ierr)
    call MPI_Type_size(MPI_CHARACTER, charsize, ierr)
    extent = localsize*charsize
    begin  = 0
    call MPI_Type_create_resized(newtype, begin, extent, resizedtype, ierr)
    call MPI_Type_commit(resizedtype, ierr)

    counts = 1          ! we will send one of these new types to everyone
    forall( col=1:procgridsize, row=1:procgridsize )
       displs(1+(row-1)+procgridsize*(col-1)) = (row-1) + localsize*procgridsize*(col-1)
    endforall

    call MPI_Scatterv(global, counts, displs,   & ! proc i gets counts(i) types from displs(i)
            resizedtype,                        &
            local, localsize**2, MPI_CHARACTER, & ! I'm receiving localsize**2 chars
            root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)           !... from (root, MPI_COMM_WORLD)

    do p=1, comsize
        if (rank == p-1) then
            print *, 'Rank ', rank, ' received: '
            do i=1, localsize
                print *, local(i,:)
            enddo
        endif
        call MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    enddo

    local = achar( ichar(local) + 1 )

    do p=1, comsize
        if (rank == p-1) then
            print *, 'Rank ', rank, ' sending: '
            do i=1, localsize
                print *, local(i,:)
            enddo
        endif
        call MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    enddo

    call MPI_Gatherv( local, localsize**2, MPI_CHARACTER, & ! I'm sending localsize**2 chars
                      global, counts, displs, resizedtype,&
                      root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

    if (rank == root) then
        print *, ' Root received: '
        do i=1,gridsize
            print *, global(i,:)
        enddo
    endif

    call MPI_Type_free(newtype,ierr)
    if (rank == root) deallocate(global)
    deallocate(local)
    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)

end program scatter
```

So that's the general solution.  For your particular case, where we are just appending by rows, we don't need a Gatherv, we can just use a gather, because in this case, all of the displacements are the same -- before, in the 2d block case we had one displacement going 'down', and then jumps in that displacement as you went 'across' to the next column of blocks.  Here, the displacement is always one extent from the previous one, so we don't need  to give displacements explicitly.   So a final code looks like:

```
program testmpi
use mpi
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: send, recv
    integer, parameter :: nsendrows = 2, nsendcols = 3
    integer, parameter :: root = 0
    integer :: ierror, my_rank, comsize, i, j, ierr
    integer :: blocktype, resizedtype
    integer, dimension(2) :: starts, sizes, subsizes
    integer (kind=MPI_Address_kind) :: start, extent
    integer :: intsize

    call MPI_Init(ierror)
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_rank, ierror)
    call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, comsize, ierror)

    allocate( send(nsendrows, nsendcols) )

    send = my_rank

    if (my_rank==root) then
        ! we're going to append the local arrays
        ! as groups of send rows
        allocate( recv(nsendrows*comsize, nsendcols) )
    endif

    ! describe what these subblocks look like inside the full concatenated array
    sizes    = [ nsendrows*comsize, nsendcols ]
    subsizes = [ nsendrows, nsendcols ]
    starts   = [ 0, 0 ]

    call MPI_Type_create_subarray( 2, sizes, subsizes, starts,     &
                                   MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_INTEGER, &
                                   blocktype, ierr)

    start = 0
    call MPI_Type_size(MPI_INTEGER, intsize, ierr)
    extent = intsize * nsendrows

    call MPI_Type_create_resized(blocktype, start, extent, resizedtype, ierr)
    call MPI_Type_commit(resizedtype, ierr)

    call MPI_Gather( send, nsendrows*nsendcols, MPI_INTEGER, &  ! everyone send 3*2 ints
                     recv, 1, resizedtype,                   &  ! root gets 1 resized type from everyone
                     root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

    if (my_rank==0) then
    print*,'<><><><><>recv'
    do i=1,nsendrows*comsize
        print*,(recv(i,j),j=1,nsendcols)
    enddo
    endif
    call MPI_Finalize(ierror)

end program testmpi
```

Running this with 3 processes gives:

```
$ mpirun -np 3 ./testmpi
 <><><><><>recv
           0           0           0
           0           0           0
           1           1           1
           1           1           1
           2           2           2
           2           2           2
```

Comment: Given how long it took to re-do the code example, maybe it was worth doing a Fortran version.

Comment: @JonathanDursi I think that this answer should be copied in the documentation, since it is definitely excellent.

Comment: Updated to include edit proposed by eagle-eyed @EnricoMariaDeAngelis (and mistakenly but well-meaningly rejected by reviewers) to fix too-literal copying of indices from C example in one example.

Comment: We can certainly do that, @EnricoMariaDeAngelis

Comment: We? I would never steal your excellent answer ;) By the way, I posted a request [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mpi/topic-requests/4810).

Comment: @JonathanDursi Thanks for the great answer. But I have some problems in using the subarray approach. I am not able to get this to work for row sizes greater than 30. May be I am missing something very basic? For example, if you run the final code (testmpi program) with nsendrows = 31, nsendcols = 50 and run with 6 processes, it fails. It fails similarly for any number of processes when the number of local rows are greater than 30. I tried the same with the strided vector also. I ran into the exact same problem there as well. Please help!

Comment: Very strangely, if I use Gatherv with explicit setting of counts to 1 and displacements to (0,1,2..,nprocs-1), then it works for all sizes. But as you have said, Gather simply should assume these and work (which it does for small sizes).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another code block for any other struggling Fortran beginners out there like myself. It shows two different ways to achieve a `MPI_Gather` on a `nx * ny` array divided into `M * N` blocks, with one block on each process.

One way uses MPI derived datatypes, the other simply sends 1D raw data and sorts if afterward on the main node.

Both produce an ordered `M * N` 2D array. For the example of `3 x 2` sub-arrays in `x * y`, each having `4 x 5` elements:

```
n mpi ranks: 6
rank 0 has topology coords 0,0
rank 1 has topology coords 0,1
rank 2 has topology coords 1,0
rank 3 has topology coords 1,1
rank 4 has topology coords 2,0
rank 5 has topology coords 2,1
1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5
1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5
1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5
1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5
1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5
0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4
0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4
0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4
0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4
0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4
```

Note that if the raw data is sent and not re-arranged it would be ordered by default like so:

```
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The following code can be compiled with

```bash
mpif90 -Wall test.F90 -o test.out
```

and run with

```bash
mpirun -n 6 test.out
```

```fortran90
program main

use mpi
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
use iso_c_binding
implicit none

! ===
integer(int64) i, j
integer(int32) nx  , ny
integer(int32) nxr , nyr
integer(int32) npx , npy
integer(int32) ri  , rj

integer, dimension(2) :: mpi_coords, mpi_coords2
integer rank, n_ranks, ierror
integer rank_cart
integer comm, comm2d

real(real64), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: A, A_global
real(real64), dimension(:), allocatable :: B_global

integer(int32), dimension(:), allocatable :: lengths, displacements

integer(int32) subarraytype, resizedtype
integer(int32) dblsize
integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: start, extent

! === MPI interface initialization
call MPI_INIT(ierror)
comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(comm, n_ranks, ierror)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(comm, rank,    ierror)

if (rank .eq. 0) then
    print '(a, i0)', 'n mpi ranks: ', n_ranks
end if

npx = 3       !! n processes in x
nxr = 4       !! n pts per rank in x
nx  = npx*nxr !! n pts x total

npy = 2       !! n processes in y
nyr = 5       !! n pts per rank in y
ny  = npy*nyr !! n pts y total

! === check that n_ranks are equal to the hardcoded number of processes in [x,y]
if (n_ranks .ne. npx*npy) then
    if (rank .eq. 0) then
        print '(a)','n_ranks != npx*npy'
    end if
    call MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, -1, ierror)
    call MPI_Finalize(ierror)
end if
call MPI_BARRIER(comm, ierror)

! === create 2D Cartesian grid
call MPI_Cart_create(comm, 2, (/npx,npy/), (/.true.,.false./), .true., comm2d, ierror)

! === get rank in 2D communicator
call MPI_Comm_rank(comm2d, rank_cart, ierror)

! === get this rank ID and coordinates within the 2D topology
call MPI_Cart_coords(comm2d, rank_cart, 2, mpi_coords, ierror)

! === print topology
if (.true.) then
    print '(a,i0,a,i0,a,i0)', 'rank ', rank_cart, ' has topology coords ', mpi_coords(1), ',', mpi_coords(2)
end if
call MPI_BARRIER(comm, ierror)
call flush(6)

! === populate data
allocate( A(nxr,nyr) )
A(:,:) = real(rank,real64)

! ===

if (.true.) then !! use MPI derived types
    
    allocate (lengths(n_ranks))
    allocate (displacements(n_ranks))
    
    call MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, (/nx,ny/), (/nxr,nyr/), (/0,0/), &
                                  MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, subarraytype, ierror)
    call MPI_Type_size(MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dblsize, ierror)
    start  = 0
    extent = nxr*dblsize
    call MPI_Type_create_resized(subarraytype, start, extent, resizedtype, ierror)
    call MPI_Type_commit(resizedtype, ierror)
    lengths = 1
    
    !! displacements = [ npx*0*nyr+0, npx*1*nyr+0, &
    !!                   npx*0*nyr+1, npx*1*nyr+1, &
    !!                   npx*0*nyr+2, npx*1*nyr+2 ] !! for 3x2
    
    !! displacements = [ npx*0*nyr+0, npx*1*nyr+0, npx*2*nyr+0, &
    !!                   npx*0*nyr+1, npx*1*nyr+1, npx*2*nyr+1  ] !! for 2x3
    
    do i=0,n_ranks-1
        call MPI_Cart_coords(comm2d, int(i,int32), 2, mpi_coords2, ierror)
        ri = mpi_coords2(1)
        rj = mpi_coords2(2)
        displacements(i+1) = npx*rj*nyr + ri
    end do
    
    if (rank .eq. 0) then
        allocate( A_global(nx,ny) )
    end if
    
    call MPI_Gatherv( A ,       nxr*nyr, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                      A_global, lengths, displacements, resizedtype, &
                      0, comm2d, ierror )
    
else !! send raw data in 1D, then re-arrange
    
    if (rank .eq. 0) then
        allocate( A_global(nx,ny) )
        allocate( B_global(nx*ny) )
    end if
    
    call MPI_Gather( A , nxr*nyr, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                     B_global, nxr*nyr, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                     0, comm2d, ierror )
    
    if (rank .eq. 0) then
        
        if (.true.) then !! re-arrange data
            
            do i=0,n_ranks-1
                
                call MPI_Cart_coords(comm2d, int(i,int32), 2, mpi_coords2, ierror)
                
                ri = mpi_coords2(1)
                rj = mpi_coords2(2)
                
                A_global( (ri+0)*nxr+1:(ri+1)*nxr+1 , &
                          (rj+0)*nyr+1:(rj+1)*nyr+1 ) &
                          = &
                          reshape( B_global( (i+0)*nxr*nyr+1 : (i+1)*nxr*nyr+1 ) , (/nxr,nyr/) )
                
            end do
        
        else !! dont do re-arrange
            
            A_global(:,:) = reshape( B_global , (/nx,ny/) )
        
        end if
    end if
    
    if (rank .eq. 0) then
        deallocate( B_global )
    end if

end if

! ===

!! print the array to the terminal
if (rank .eq. 0) then
    do j=ny, 1, -1
        do i=1, nx
            write(*,'(i0,a)',advance='no') int(A_global(i,j)) , " "
        end do
        write (*,*) ''
    end do
end if

!! save data to binary file
if (rank==0) then
    open(3, file=trim("A.dat"), access="stream")
    write(3) reshape( A_global , (/nx,ny/) )
    close(3)
end if

if (rank .eq. 0) then
    deallocate( A_global )
end if

! ===

call MPI_BARRIER(comm, ierror)
call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)

end program main
```

A final note: pulling all data to one process (for I/O purposes or otherwise) is typically very bad practice for parallel programming. The moment this is done, the code will lose potential scalability. The method shown here is really only fit for smaller codes or for debugging. For I/O purposes, one should seriously look into collective MPI-I/O or libraries such as `HDF5` which allow for collective I/O.