# MPI_ALLGATHERV with derived data types

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am trying to use `MPI_ALLGATHERV` using derived data types. Actually, I have to pass chunks of small 3D array in the form of:

```
  SS(IIST:IIEND,JJST:JJEND,KKST:KKEND)
```

Here, `IIST`, `IIEND`, `JJST`, `JJEND`, `KKST`, `KKEND` are local indices of each process. So I tried to define a derived datatype in the following form:

```
  INTEGER :: MPII,MPJJ,MPKK

  CALL MPI_TYPE_CONTIGUOUS(IIEND-IIST+1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPII,IERR)
  CALL MPI_TYPE_CONTIGUOUS(JJEND-JJST+1,MPII,MPJJ,IERR)
  CALL MPI_TYPE_CONTIGUOUS(KKEND-KKST+1,MPJJ,MPKK,IERR)            
  CALL MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(MPKK,IERR)
```

Now, I am defining a displacement array which is visible to every process to be used in `MPI_ALLGATHERV`. The total number of processes is 27 and they are numbered from 0-26.

```
  DO NT=0,26
  DISPL(1)=0
  IF (NT.GT.0) DISPL(NT+1)= DISPL(NT)+1 
  ENDDO
```

Now, I am executing `MPI_ALLGATHERV` with the following syntax:

```
  CALL MPI_ALLGATHERV(SS(IIST:IIEND,JJST:JJEND,KKST:KKEND),SPANX*SPANY*SPANZ,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,SS(1,1,1),1,DISPL,MPKK,MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)
```

This is giving me error. Any pointers in this problem will be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: The trouble may come from the argument `recvcount`. It is supposed to be an array of 27 integers and you wrote `SS(1,1,1),1,DISPL,`  http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Allgatherv.html

Comment: Thanks Francis. Now the error is gone but still the output is incorrect.

Comment: Do you have garbage in the array or numbers at the wrong place ? I also found this issue and its answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508647/sending-2d-arrays-in-fortran-with-mpi-gather and http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Type_create_subarray.html. These pieces of code and functions may be useful to get the correct layout.

Comment: I will try that and get back here soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
  spanx = iiend-iist+1
  spany = jjend-jjst+1
  spanz = kkend-kkst+1

  oldsize = (/spanx,spany,spanz/)
  newsize = (/spanx,spany,spanz/) 
  starts  = (/0,0,0/) 

  CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY(3,OLDSIZE,NEWSIZE,STARTS,MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,ARR,IERR)
  CALL MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(ARR,IERR)

  DO NT=0,26
  DISPL(1)=0
  IF (NT.GT.0) DISPL(NT+1)= DISPL(NT)+1 
  SIZECC(NT)=1
  ENDDO

  CALL MPI_ALLGATHERV(SS(IIST:IIEND,JJST:JJEND,KKST:KKEND),SPANX*SPANY*SPANZ,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,SS(1,1,1),SIZECC,DISPL,ARR,MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)
```

Still the output doesn`t match. I think something is wrong in Displacement array.