# Partition a 3D array AND use allgather

Tags: fortran, mpi, partitioning

I now want to use the allgather to rebuild a 3D array. 16 cups are claimed and the data of the Y-Z plane are partitioned into 4*4 parts.
Also a new type (newtype) is created for convenience. 
Are the errors related to this new type, Thanks!

```
!==================================================================================================================================
!****** [  Program main  ] ********************************************************************************************************
!==================================================================================================================================
program main
  Use mpi

  implicit none
  integer i, j, k, count, realsize  

  integer, parameter :: nx = 8, ny = 8, nz = 8
  Integer            :: interval

  real(4), dimension(nx,ny,nz):: u_xyz
  Real(4),dimension(:,:,:), allocatable ::  Temp0
! === MPI Related ===
   Integer, Parameter    :: master = 0
   Integer               :: ierr,  num_procs, myid, p_row, p_col, newtype, resizedtype 
   integer, save :: MPI_COMM_CART  

   integer, dimension(2) :: dims, coord   
   Integer, Dimension(2) :: R_coord, C_coord, MPGD             
   Integer, Dimension(3) :: sizes, subsizes, starts     
   integer,dimension(:),allocatable :: displacement
   integer(kind=mpi_address_kind) :: lb, extent 

   logical, dimension(2) :: periodic    

!--------------=======--------------
!  Initialize MPI
!
  call MPI_Init ( ierr )
!
!  Get the number of processes.
!
  call MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs, ierr )
!
!  Get the individual process ID.
!
  call MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr )
!--------------=======--------------
!     Y-Z PLANE SPLIT
!--------------=======--------------   
    p_row = 4; p_col = 4
    If(p_row*p_col .NE. num_procs) Print *, 'Wrong CPU Numbers'
!--------------=======--------------
    dims(1) = p_row
    dims(2) = p_col
    periodic(1) = .false.
    periodic(2) = .false.
    call MPI_CART_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,2,dims,periodic, &
         .false., &  ! do not reorder rank
         MPI_COMM_CART, ierr)
    call MPI_CART_COORDS(MPI_COMM_CART,myid,2,coord,ierr)

!--------------=======--------------
!----------YZ Plane Locations-----
!--------------=======--------------
  Interval = Ceiling(dble(ny)/dble(p_row)) 

  If (coord(1) .NE. p_row-1 ) then
    R_coord(1) = 1 + (coord(1))*Interval 
    R_coord(2) = R_coord(1) + Interval - 1 
  Else
    R_coord(1) = 1 + coord(1)*Interval 
    R_coord(2) = ny
  End If

  Interval = Ceiling(dble(nz)/dble(p_col)) 

  If (coord(2) .NE. p_col-1 ) then
    C_coord(1) = 1 + (coord(2))*Interval 
    C_coord(2) = C_coord(1) + Interval - 1 
  Else
    C_coord(1) = 1 + (coord(2))*Interval 
    C_coord(2) = nz
  End If  

!--------------=======--------------
!----------Obtain displacement-----
!--------------=======--------------  
!  COUNT = 0
!  DO K=1,nz
!    DO J=1,ny
!      DO I=1,nx
!   If(i==1.and.j== R_coord(1).and.k==C_coord(1)) print *, myid, R_coord(1), C_coord(1), COUNT 
!        COUNT = COUNT + 1
!      ENDDO
!    ENDDO
!  ENDDO

  allocate(Temp0(nx,R_coord(1):R_coord(2),C_coord(1):C_coord(2)))!
  allocate(displacement(num_procs))

  Do k=C_coord(1),C_coord(2)
  Do j=R_coord(1),R_coord(2)
  Do i=1,nx
       u_xyz(i,j,k)= i+j+k
  End Do; End Do
  End Do

  Do i=0,num_procs-1
    displacement(i)= (i/4)*(16) + mod(i,4)*128
!   if(myid==0)    print *, i, displacement(i)
  Enddo  

!--------------=======--------------
! ---  Create the same block type ---
!--------------=======--------------  
     sizes(1) = nx
     sizes(2) = ny
     sizes(3) = nz

     subsizes(1) = nx
     subsizes(2) = R_coord(2)-R_coord(1)+1
     subsizes(3) = C_coord(2)-C_coord(1)+1

     starts(1) = 0  ! 0-based index
     starts(2) = 0
     starts(3) = 0

    call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY(3, sizes, subsizes, starts,         &
          MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_REAL, newtype, ierr)

    call MPI_Type_size(MPI_REAL, realsize, ierr)
    extent = 1*realsize
    lb = 0
    call MPI_Type_create_resized(newtype, lb, extent, resizedtype, ierr)
    call MPI_Type_commit(resizedtype, ierr)


    Call MPI_Allgather(Temp0(1,R_coord(1),C_coord(1)),resizedtype,    &
                        1, u_xyz, resizedtype, displacement,          &
                1, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
    call MPI_TYPE_FREE(newtype,ierr)



  777   Format(15e25.16e3)
  Call MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr) 
  Call MPI_Finalize ( ierr )   
  stop  
end program main
```

The code had some error messages as follows:

```
[desktop:18885] *** An error occurred in MPI_Allgather
[desktop:18885] *** reported by process [139648622723073,139646566662149]
[desktop:18885] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_SELF
[desktop:18885] *** MPI_ERR_TYPE: invalid datatype
[desktop:18885] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[desktop:18885] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[31373,1],0]
  Exit code:    3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[desktop:18878] 7 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal
[desktop:18878] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

Comment: The call to `MPI_Allgather` is incorrect with several arguments out of order or missing. For instance the sending type  should be the third and the count should be second. There's no error return code and `MPI_Allgather` doesn't take a `displacement` argument. `MPI_Allgatherv` does. Also it looks like you have the sends and receives reversed.

Comment: Read very carefully [this canonical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17530368/1374437) and adapt it to your 3D case.

Comment: @RussF It works, Thanks.

Comment: @HristoIliev Really good example which you gave. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code. Thanks to the comments above. Care should be taken when defining the type, such as.

recvcounts
       **integer array** (of length group size) containing the number of elements that are to be received from each process

displs
       **integer array** (of length group size). Entry i specifies the displacement (relative to recvbuf ) at which to place the incoming
   data from process i  recvtype

```
!==================================================================================================================================
    !****** [  Program main  ] ********************************************************************************************************
    !==================================================================================================================================
    program main
      Use mpi

      implicit none
      integer i, j, k,ii
      integer count, realsize  

      integer, parameter :: nx = 8, ny = 8, nz = 8
      Integer            :: interval

      real(4), dimension(nx*ny*nz):: u_xyz
      Real(4),dimension(:,:,:), allocatable ::  Temp0
    ! === MPI Related ===
       Integer, Parameter    :: master = 0
       Integer               :: ierr,  num_procs, myid, p_row, p_col, newtype, resizedsd, resizedrv 
       integer, save :: MPI_COMM_CART  

       integer, dimension(2) :: dims, coord   
       Integer, Dimension(2) :: R_coord, C_coord, MPGD             
       Integer, Dimension(3) :: sizes, subsizes, starts     
       integer,dimension(:),allocatable :: displacement, recvcnt
       integer(kind=mpi_address_kind) :: lb, extent 

       logical, dimension(2) :: periodic    

    !--------------=======--------------
    !  Initialize MPI
    !
      call MPI_Init ( ierr )
    !
    !  Get the number of processes.
    !
      call MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs, ierr )
    !
    !  Get the individual process ID.
    !
      call MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr )
    !--------------=======--------------
    !     Y-Z PLANE SPLIT
    !--------------=======--------------   
        p_row = 4; p_col = 4
        If(p_row*p_col .NE. num_procs) Print *, 'Wrong CPU Numbers'
    !--------------=======--------------
        dims(1) = p_row
        dims(2) = p_col
        periodic(1) = .false.
        periodic(2) = .false.
        call MPI_CART_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,2,dims,periodic, &
             .false., &  ! do not reorder rank
             MPI_COMM_CART, ierr)
        call MPI_CART_COORDS(MPI_COMM_CART,myid,2,coord,ierr)

    !--------------=======--------------
    !----------YZ Plane Locations-----
    !--------------=======--------------
      Interval = Ceiling(dble(ny)/dble(p_row)) 

      If (coord(1) .NE. p_row-1 ) then
        R_coord(1) = 1 + (coord(1))*Interval 
        R_coord(2) = R_coord(1) + Interval - 1 
      Else
        R_coord(1) = 1 + coord(1)*Interval 
        R_coord(2) = ny
      End If

      Interval = Ceiling(dble(nz)/dble(p_col)) 

      If (coord(2) .NE. p_col-1 ) then
        C_coord(1) = 1 + (coord(2))*Interval 
        C_coord(2) = C_coord(1) + Interval - 1 
      Else
        C_coord(1) = 1 + (coord(2))*Interval 
        C_coord(2) = nz
      End If  

    !--------------=======--------------
    !----------Obtain displacement-----
    !--------------=======--------------  
    !  COUNT = 0
    !  DO K=1,nz
    !    DO J=1,ny
    !      DO I=1,nx
    !   If(i==1.and.j== R_coord(1).and.k==C_coord(1)) print *, myid, R_coord(1), C_coord(1), COUNT 
    !        COUNT = COUNT + 1
    !      ENDDO
    !    ENDDO
    !  ENDDO

      allocate(Temp0(1:nx,R_coord(1):R_coord(2),C_coord(1):C_coord(2)))!
      allocate(displacement(num_procs),recvcnt(num_procs))  
      Do k=C_coord(1),C_coord(2)
      Do j=R_coord(1),R_coord(2)
      Do i=1,nx
           Temp0(i,j,k)= i+j*10+k*100
      End Do; End Do
      End Do

      Do i=1,num_procs
         ii = i-1
        displacement(i)= (ii/4)*(16) + mod(ii,4)*128
    !   if(myid==0)    print *, i, displacement(i)
      Enddo  

    !--------------=======--------------
    ! ---  Create the same block type ---
    !--------------=======--------------  
         sizes(1) = nx
         sizes(2) = ny
         sizes(3) = nz

         subsizes(1) = nx
         subsizes(2) = R_coord(2)-R_coord(1)+1
         subsizes(3) = C_coord(2)-C_coord(1)+1

         starts(1) = 0  ! 0-based index
         starts(2) = 0
         starts(3) = 0
         recvcnt(:)= 1
        call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY(3, sizes, subsizes, starts,         &
              MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_REAL, newtype, ierr)

        call MPI_Type_size(MPI_REAL, realsize, ierr)
        extent = 1*realsize

        lb = 0
        call MPI_Type_create_resized(newtype, lb, extent, resizedrv, ierr)
        call MPI_Type_commit(resizedrv, ierr)


        Call MPI_AllgatherV(Temp0(1,R_coord(1),C_coord(1)), subsizes(1)*subsizes(2)*subsizes(3), MPI_REAL,  &
                           u_xyz, recvcnt,displacement, resizedrv,  MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        call MPI_TYPE_FREE(resizedrv,ierr)

    !    If(myid.eq.10) then     
    !    Count = 0
    !    do k=1,nz
    !    do J=1,ny
    !    do i=1,nx
    !    Count = Count + 1
    !    print*, u_xyz(count)- (i+j*10+k*100), i,j,k
    !   enddo; enddo;  enddo
    !   end if

      777   Format(15e25.16e3)
      Call MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr) 
      Call MPI_Finalize ( ierr )   
      stop  
    end program main
```