# MPI_GATHERV (Fortran) to create a new 2D matrix from 2D sub matrices

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran, mpi

I am trying to gather sub-2D arrays, which have different numbers of rows but have the same numbers of columns, into a global 2D array. For example, assuming to use 2 MPI processes, the first process (i.e., rank == 0) has:

```
local = [11,12,13,14]
```

, and the second process (i.e., rank == 1) has:

```
local = [21,22,23,24
         31,32,33,34]
```

Then, I want to concatenate these two arrays into one 2D array as:

```
global = [11,12,13,14
          21,22,23,24
          31,32,33,34]
```

Since each "local" array has a different number of rows, I (may) want to use mpi_gatherv (or mpi_allgatherv). I found identical problems here: [Using Gatherv for 2d Arrays in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221649/using-gatherv-for-2d-arrays-in-fortran) and [Using MPI_gatherv to create a new matrix from other smaller matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701506/using-mpi-gatherv-to-create-a-new-matrix-from-other-smaller-matrices), but I still don't quite understand. So, please teach me. Here is my example code:

```
program main
use mpi
implicit none
   
integer :: i, j
integer :: rank, npro, ierr
integer, allocatable :: local(:,:)
integer, allocatable :: global(:,:), displs(:), counts(:)
integer :: loc_size(2), glob_size(2), starts(2) 
integer :: newtype, int_size, resizedtype
integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: extent, begin
! End of local variables ==================================================!

call MPI_Init(ierr)
call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, npro, ierr)

! I will set local 2D arrays as: [1,4] for rank #0, and [2,4] for rank #1
! then, the global 2D array will be [3,4] (assuming I use 2 processes)
loc_size  = [rank+1,4]      ! [1,4], [2,4]
glob_size = [3,4]           ! I will use npro = 2

! allocate local and global arrays
allocate(local(loc_size(1),   loc_size(2))) ! [1,4], [2,4]
allocate(global(glob_size(1), glob_size(2)))! [3,4] ! if npro = 2

! set "local" array
!       rank = 0: [11, 12, 13, 14]
!       rank = 1: [21, 22, 23, 24
!                  31, 32, 33, 34]
if(rank == 0) then
   do j=1,4
      local(1,j) = 10 + j ! [11,12,13,14]
   end do
else if(rank == 1) then
   do i=1,2
      do j=1,4
         local(i,j) = (i+1)*10 + j ! [21,22,23,24; 31,32,33,34]
      end do
   end do
end if


! create a 2D subarray and set as "newtype" 
starts    = [0,0]              ! array start location
call MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, glob_size, loc_size, starts, &
&                             MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_INTEGER, &
&                             newtype, ierr)

! get MPI_INTEGER type size in byte
! I don't quite understand the following processes...
! So, please comment on each step if possible...
call MPI_Type_size(MPI_INTEGER, int_size, ierr)
begin  =  0
extent =  (rank+1) * int_size ! rank 0 = 4 byte; rank 1 = 8 byte (am I doing correct here?)
call MPI_Type_create_resized(newtype, begin, extent, resizedtype, ierr) ! I dont' quite understand this process
call MPI_Type_commit(resizedtype, ierr)

! allocate index for mpi_gatherv
allocate(displs(npro)) ! [2], index for mpi_gatherv
allocate(counts(npro)) ! [2], index for mpi_gatherv

counts = [1,1]
do i =  1,npro
   displs(i) = (i-1) ! [0,1]
end do

call MPI_Gatherv(local, 1, MPI_INTEGER,               &
&                global, counts, displs, resizedtype, &
&                0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

if(rank == 0) then
   do i=1,3
      write(*,*) (global(i,j), j=1,4)
   end do
end if

call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
end program main
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I understand your `global` picture correctly and you are using column-major storage, then you indeed need `Type_create_resized` because the contributions from the processes will be interleaved. But you don't need the subarray type. Try it without: make a contiguous type and lower the extent to the column size.

Comment: Your code is really hard to debug as your matrix is square so it is difficult to see if row and column sizes have been interchanged. Setting the second (fixed) dimension to 4 rather than 3 would make it much easier to debug, and initialise the data to different values - they are currently constant per rank, making it impossible to see which data is going where.

Comment: @David Henty - Thank you for the comment. I have changed the code following your suggestion.

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout - Can you elaborate more with a code?

Comment: @Jungwoo Sorry, I don't have time to write your program for you. 1. you are sending contiguous buffers so your send buffer is fine. 2. if you write out where the send buffers wind up in the receive buffer you see a bunch of interleaved strided blocks. So I think you need `Type_vector`, where you resize the extent to the size of just one block. Your `subarray` type is also correct, except that with the start point all zero it's equivalent to a vector type. Just harder to read.

Just curious: what is the context that makes you do this?

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout - Thank you. I will try to use vector type as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be a lot easier if you changed the storage order (i.e. have rank "i" initialise "i+1" columns of fixed length), but the following code seems to work for what you currently have. I have turned on debug output, changed the number of columns to 4, ran on 3 processes (so the global number of rows = 1+2+3 = 6) and made sure the local arrays are initialised with unique data.

An important point is that you need a different send type for each rank as the strides are different (since the local arrays are of different dimensions). Maybe there's a much easier way to do this (without changing the storage order) but at least this seems to work.

Note that the comments no longer correlate with the actual code!

```
program main
use mpi
implicit none
   
integer :: i, j
integer :: rank, npro, ierr
integer, allocatable :: local(:,:)
integer, allocatable :: global(:,:), displs(:), counts(:)
integer :: loc_size(2), glob_size(2), starts(2) 
integer :: newtype, int_size, stype, resizedstype, rtype, resizedrtype
integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: extent, begin
! End of local variables ==================================================!

call MPI_Init(ierr)
call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, npro, ierr)

! I will set local 2D arrays as: [1,3] for rank #0, and [2,3] for rank #1
! then, the global 2D array will be [3,3] (assuming I use 2 processes)
loc_size  = [rank+1,4]      ! [1,3], [2,3]
glob_size = [6,4]           ! I will use npro = 3

! allocate local and global arrays
allocate(local(loc_size(1),   loc_size(2))) ! [1,3], [2,3]
allocate(global(glob_size(1), glob_size(2)))! [3,3] ! if npro = 2

! set "local" array
!       rank = 0: [0, 0, 0]
!       rank = 1: [1, 1, 1
!                  1, 1, 1]
do i=1,rank+1
   do j=1,4
      local(i,j) = 10*rank+4*(i-1)+j
   end do
end do

! check the local array 
 do i=1,rank+1
    write(*,*) 'rank = ', rank, 'local = ', (local(i,j), j=1,4)
 end do

! create a 2D subarray and set as send type stype 
loc_size= [1,4]
starts    = [0,0]              ! array start location
glob_size=[rank+1,4]
call MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, glob_size, loc_size, starts, &
&                             MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_INTEGER, &
&                             stype, ierr)

! get MPI_INTEGER type size in byte
call MPI_Type_size(MPI_INTEGER, int_size, ierr)
begin  =  0
extent =  int_size

call MPI_Type_create_resized(stype, begin, extent, resizedstype, ierr)
call MPI_Type_commit(resizedstype, ierr)

 ! create a 2D subarray and set as receive type rtype 
loc_size=[1,4]
starts    = [0,0]              ! array start location
glob_size=[6,4]
call MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, glob_size, loc_size, starts, &
&                             MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_INTEGER, &
&                             rtype, ierr)

! get MPI_INTEGER type size in byte
! I don't quite understand the following processes...
! So, please comment on each step if possible...
call MPI_Type_size(MPI_INTEGER, int_size, ierr)
begin  =  0
extent =  int_size

call MPI_Type_create_resized(rtype, begin, extent, resizedrtype, ierr)
call MPI_Type_commit(resizedrtype, ierr)

! allocate index for mpi_gatherv
allocate(displs(npro)) ! [2], index for mpi_gatherv
allocate(counts(npro)) ! [2], index for mpi_gatherv

counts = [1,2,3]
displs = [0,1,3]
call MPI_Gatherv(local, rank+1, resizedstype,               &
&                global, counts, displs, resizedrtype, &
&                0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

if(rank == 0) then
   do i=1,6
      write(*,*) (global(i,j), j=1,4)
   end do
end if

call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
end program main
```

If I run on 3 processes I get sensible results:

```
 rank =            0 local =            1           2           3           4
 rank =            1 local =           11          12          13          14
 rank =            1 local =           15          16          17          18
 rank =            2 local =           21          22          23          24
 rank =            2 local =           25          26          27          28
 rank =            2 local =           29          30          31          32
           1           2           3           4
          11          12          13          14
          15          16          17          18
          21          22          23          24
          25          26          27          28
          29          30          31          32
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Now, I think what was my problem. I will also try the way Victor commented.